# What are the implications of using lock(typeof(string))

Tags: c#

We had a discussion at work regarding locking and what exactly happens. The code that triggered this discussion is:

```
        string name = (string)context.Cache[key];

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name)){

            lock (typeof(string)){
                name = (string)context.Cache[key];
                //.. other code to get the name and then store in the cache
            }
        }
```

I see this as straight-forward: look for a value in the cache, if it's not there then get a lock so as nothing else interrupts whilst the code gets the name and stores it in the cache.

Our discussion focused on whether (typeof(string)) is the best way of doing things, and what exactly is does.

My question is what exactly does lock(typeof(string)) do? Does it create a local string to be used a lock or is it creating something with a wider scope and therefore potentially un-safe.

[MSDN lock statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: No, it locks on the whole type - [and it can be dangerous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603008/why-is-lock-typeof-mytype-a-problem). If it just created a random string to lock on, how would other locks know to lock on the same instance of that string? I would recommend you just make a dummy object to lock on like `private object _lockOnThis = new object()`.

Comment: I think typeof(SomeType) will always return the same Type instance for the same type. So you would use a globally available instance as a lock which is not the best idea IMHO.

Comment: @vcsjones I'm currently removing all instances of this way of locking but was interested in what exactly it did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you lock on a `Type` it will mean that you have a mutual access exclusion based on that instance of the `Type`. The implications are that two threads in the application doing this will inadvertently block each other or cause unforeseen deadlocks.

Remember, `typeof(someType)` just returns a `Type` instance.

It is typically a best practice to dedicate an object to locking a complex process, such as declaring a `readonly object` in your class. If the lock just needs to go around some access to a private variable, say a collection, then locking that collection is quite fine.

Comment: This was the conclusion we eventually reached in our discussion.

Comment: I wasn't certain whether to accept Jon Skeet's answer or Michael's since both are good answers. Mike's got less points so that swung it.

Answer (score 8):

> My question is what exactly does lock(typeof(string)) do?

It locks on the `Type` object referred to by the reference that the `typeof` operator returns.

That means *any* code which does the same thing *anywhere* within the same process (or at least the same AppDomain) will share the same lock. Sounds like a bad idea to me.

I would suggest you create an object *just* for locking on:

```
private static readonly object CacheLock = new object();

...

lock (CacheLock)
{
    ...
}
```

That way you can easily see what's going to lock on that object.

Comment: What would the benefit of locking on a dedicated object be over locking on the principal shared resource? Say if this cache is just an object that is declared in the same fashion as your `CacheLock`.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray: It means you can easily check what's locking on that object. Do you know whether any code within .NET itself locks on the cache? I don't.

Comment: I guess I am a little confused with your comment. How is it easier to check if something is locking on `CacheLock` rather than the cache you are going to be accessing (not typeof(Cache) mind you)? If I have a `lock (this.cache) { .. }` it should be more correct, I believe. I am uncertain as to why the trend has begun with making something like `lock (this.cacheLocker) { .. }` against single objects; I can understand the `cacheLocker` for complex processes where types are internally thread safe and expose public thread safe methods.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray: `CacheLock` is private. I can easily see all the code which can see it at all. Lots of code *could* access the `Cache` - anything which can use `context.Cache`, for starters...

Comment: Fair enough. I suppose it is applicable to lock the resource (nearly) only when your shared resource is not private and has the ability to be accessed outside of its parent class.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray: Well don't forget that if you do anything *with* the resource, that might lock on `this`, too. Personally I wish we didn't have the ability to lock on arbitrary objects...

Comment: Ah, yes. That is very true. If the shared resource is locking on `this`, as was common a long time ago, before the SyncRoot practice, you would run into some unnecessary contention and possibly deadlocks. Good point! I don't believe locking on `this` is a recommended practice anymore, but I could be wrong. I do agree though, it would be cool to have a lock statement that locks on everything inside its scope instead of letting you specify arbitrary objects; but then it would be annoying to make special locks for complicated concurrent execution plans.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray: That's not what I was suggesting at all - I was suggesting that you should *only* be able to lock on specific types (e.g. make `Monitor` a non-static class...)

Comment: My apologies. I thought of an idea and my mind ran with it. I get what you mean now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As shown on the page you link to:

> In general, avoid locking on a public type, or instances beyond your code's control. The common constructs lock (this), lock (typeof (MyType)), and lock ("myLock") violate this guideline:
>
> `lock (typeof (MyType))` is a problem if `MyType` is publicly accessible.