# what object type/instance to use for synchronization

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, locking

I have seen different variations of objects used when acquiring a lock

1. A static private object

   ```
   public class MyClass
   {
     private static object syncBlock = new object();

     private void MyMethod()
     {
         lock (syncBlock)
         {

         }
     }
   ```

   }
2. A class level private object

   ```
   public class MyClass
   {
      private object syncBlock = new object();

      private void MyMethod()
      {
          lock (syncBlock)
          {

          }
      }
   }
   ```
3. using the type itself

   ```
   public class MyClass
   {
      private void MyMethod()
      {
          lock (typeof (MyClass))
          {

          }
      }
   }
   ```
4. using this:

   ```
   public class MyClass
   {
      private void MyMethod()
      {
         lock (this)
         {

         }
      }
   }
   ```

Can someone elaborate what are the pro/cons of each of these and if one should be preferred over others in a given scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad) `lock(this)`.

[Don't use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603008/why-is-lock-typeof-mytype-a-problem) `lock(typeof(MyClass))` either.

As for `static` vs `instance`, it depends on what is appropriate for you. If you use a `static private object`, then **all instances of your class will share the lock**. If you use a `private object` that is not static, then each instance will have its own lock. So there is no pro/cons, it depends on what you need.

Comment: Thanks ken2k. The whole idea of locking is to protect data from multiple instances. Based on that shouldn't we always have a static. Can you provide any uses cases where we should not be using static?

Comment: @PaulSnow When you want to modify instance fields/properties of the type.