# Is it possible to have C# async method return type to be something not Task<T> or void?

Tags: c#, async-await

It seems that any object that implements the `GetAwaiter` requirements can be awaited upon, the `Task<>` type is just one of the many possible types that satisfy this requirement. However, it seems that an `async` method can only return either `Task<>` or `void`as far as I know. Is it possible to hook up my custom task alike awaitable type, so I can specify my custom awaitable types as async return type, then of course I can subsequently chain the `await` up the calling chain normally. Something like: (pseudo code)

```
async MyAwaitable MyAwaitableMethod()
{
    await myAwaitable;
}

async Task MyTask()
{
    await MyAwaitableMethod();
}
```

*Background info*: the whole idea actually stems from the C++1z/2x coroutine proposal, which has largely the same basic model, but it allows more control in defining any type that has an embedded `promise_type` to be returned from the coroutine (as a consequence of `co_await`).

***[EDIT]***

In addition to the links provided in the answer, I've found some more information in the following links, which seem that there indeed had been some hot discussion about this topic:

1. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7169
2. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/10902
3. https://github.com/ljw1004/roslyn/blob/features/async-return/docs/specs/feature%20-%20arbitrary%20async%20returns%20-%20discussion.md

***[EDIT2]***

Surprisingly, after some further digging, this is actually a prospective feature of C# 7.0: http://intellitect.com/generalized-async-return-types/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375491/inheriting-task-class-in-c-sharp-4-0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UPDATE: The feature referred to in this question from 2017 was in fact implemented in C# 7.0; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types for details.

Original answer from 2017 follows:

---

The feature you want does not exist. It has been proposed and I believe there is a prototype implementation. See

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/16476

for the design notes.

If this subject interests you, consider also looking into the design work for a generalized coroutine feature in Kotlin.  Good stuff here.

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-coroutines/blob/master/kotlin-coroutines-informal.md

Comment: Thanks, this helped me understand the scope of the current async/await facilities better!

Comment: I believe it exists now, but it does not seem to be well-documented (at least, I have not found a good example yet): https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753797/2173353