# In C#7, how can I "roll my own" Task-like type to use with async?

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-7.0

One of the less-talked-about features of C#7 is "generalized async return types", which is described by Microsoft as:

*Returning a Task object from async methods can introduce performance bottlenecks in certain paths. Task is a reference type, so using it means allocating an object. In cases where a method declared with the async modifier returns a cached result, or completes synchronously, the extra allocations can become a significant time cost in performance critical sections of code. It can become very costly if those allocations occur in tight loops.*

*The new language feature means that async methods may return other types in addition to `Task`, `Task<T>` and `void`. The returned type must still satisfy the async pattern, meaning a GetAwaiter method must be accessible. As one concrete example, the ValueTask type has been added to the .NET framework to make use of this new language feature:*

That sounds great, but I cannot for the life of my find any example that doesn't just use the stock `ValueTask<T>` type.  I want to make my own Task-like type.  Specifically I want a type that behaves like a `Task<T>`, but with a more functional style of error handling.

Here is the type I am using for functional error handling in my project:

```
public class Try<T> {
    public T Data { get; }
    public Exception Error { get; }

    public bool HasData => Error == null;
    public bool HasError => Error != null;

    public Try(T data) {
        Data = data;
    }

    public Try(Exception error) {
        Error = error;
    }
}
```

Here is what I think my custom awaitable type should look like:

```
public class TryTask<T> : Task<Try<T>> {

    public TryTask(Func<Try<T>> func)
        : base(func) { }

    //GetAwaiter is defined on base type, so we should be okay there
}
```

This all compiles, until I try to use it as an async return type:

```
async TryTask<int> DoWhatever() {
    return await new TryTask<int>(() => new Try<int>(1));
}
```

This method will give the compiler error *The return type of an async method must be void, Task, or Task.*

How do I make this or something like it compile?

---

Update:

To confirm, I am using the VS 2017 release from 3/7, and I am able to use other C#7 features in my project, such as local functions.

I have also tried using `ValueTask` and am getting the same compiler error.

```
static async ValueTask<int> DoWhatever() {
    return await new ValueTask<int>(1);          
}
```

---

Here's another post that sheds some light on whats going on.
[How do I get the new async semantics working in VS2017 RC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133510/how-do-i-get-the-new-async-semantics-working-in-vs2017-rc)

Apparently a separate "method builder" type needs to be defined and special attributes need to be applied to the awaitable type.  I don't know if I really have time to dig into this. It seems more like metaprogramming hackery than a "language feature".

Comment: Just to confirm....are any other C# 7 features working in your project?

Comment: I can make local functions.  I am also running 2017 release and targeting .NET 4.6.2

Comment: It's not hackery, you're just using an attribute to inform the compiler that the type is to be treated as "task-like". But yes, you'll need to apply the attribute in an appropriate fashion.

Comment: Well, the attribute must be applied, and it takes a parameter of type `Type`, which must be some method-builder type.  So now I need to define that type.  But the problem also arises that I'm trying to create a generic task type, so my method-builder should be generic, but you can't pass genetic types to attribute arguments.

Comment: Do you use any additional plugins / extensions except visual Studio itself?

Comment: I did have a few plugins enabled.  I disabled all of them and am still having the same issue.

Comment: For posterity, Dixin's blog has a fantastic writeup with an example. https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/functional-csharp-asynchronous-function Dixin's blog is a treasure trove. Also, there's a real example of an implementation here: https://github.com/nessos/Eff/blob/master/src/Eff.Core/Eff.cs
https://github.com/nessos/Eff/blob/master/src/Eff.Core/EffMethodBuilder.cs

Comment: Agreed, Dixin's blog is fantastic

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I couldn't find any good tutorial yet. 
But you can look at the [compiler unittests](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/5fc230a431f596fcfbb65d246573b45f164db23a/src/Compilers/CSharp/Test/Emit/CodeGen/CodeGenAsyncTests.cs) which create such task-like types (look for "[AsyncMethodBuilder").

The starting point is to create a type and mark it as task-like with an attribute like `[AsyncMethodBuilder(typeof(MyTaskBuilder))]`.
Then you need to define your own `MyTaskBuilder` type. It must implement a certain pattern (see below). That is the same pattern implemented by the regular [`AsyncMethodBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.asyncvoidmethodbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) type which supports regular `Task`.

```
class MyTaskBuilder
{
    public static MyTaskBuilder Create() => null;
    public void Start<TStateMachine>(ref TStateMachine stateMachine) where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine { }
    public void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine) { }
    public void SetResult() { }
    public void SetException(Exception exception) { }
    public MyTask Task => default(MyTask);
    public void AwaitOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(ref TAwaiter awaiter, ref TStateMachine stateMachine) where TAwaiter : INotifyCompletion where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine { }
    public void AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(ref TAwaiter awaiter, ref TStateMachine stateMachine) where TAwaiter : ICriticalNotifyCompletion where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine { }
}
```

Update: a [small spec for task-like types](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/task-types.md) was added to the compiler documents.

Comment: What are the implementation details of these task-types? I feel like these is some logic expectations that need to be explicitly documented.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell See the linked speclet for a bit more details. Also, I would look for resources that explain how `AsyncMethodBuilder` works.

Comment: This answer is really helpful, but the builders used in the `AsyncMethodBuilder` attributes of the unit tests have empty implementations. I guess they only test that it compiles or that it doesn't. I wish there was a complete example on this... I really want to create my own task-like type, in order to avoid nested-generics-hell... I've decompiled the `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<TResult>`, but it uses a lot of internal dependencies from the assembly, which I have no idea what they do...

Comment: OK, I just found this, but it seems really simpler than what I see inside the decompiled class: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/extending-the-async-methods-in-c/

Comment: If you don't do anything funky with your custom Task-like objects and want them mostly behave like regular tasks, the easiest approach would be just create AsyncTaskMethodBuilder inside your MyTaskBuilder and forward all calls to it

Comment: Are there resources that touch on the code-generation side of this that enable you to cleanly return a value result without it being wrapped in the task-like type? Ie. an async method that returns `TaskLike<int>` can just return an `int` and the compiler is happy with that, and necessary code generation occurs at compile time?

Been struggling to find resource on this.