# Prerequisites for a type to be returned async without Task?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I need to implement the `async` pattern (I hope this is what is called) on a type. So far I have added all the prerequisites in doing so.

I need to be able to do the following:

```
public async MyAsync Method()
{
   return await new MyAsync();
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
class MyAsync:INotifyCompletion
    {
        public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
        public  async MyAsync GetResult() {
            return await new MyAsync();
        }
        public MyAsync GetAwaiter() {
            return new MyAsync();
        }

        public void OnCompleted(Action continuation) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();

        }
    }
```

Still I get the compiler error highlight `The return type of an async method must be void,Task,Task<T>` on the `GetResult` method.

What can I do to solve this one?

What else should i add to my class?

Comment: Why are you trying to write your own implementation.... why not just return `Task<MyType>`

Comment: `MyAsync` inplements `INotifyCompletion`, therefor it's not a `Task<T>` object.

Comment: What's the end goal? What `await MyAsync` is supposed to do?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [In C#7, how can I “roll my own” Task-like type to use with async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42721979/in-c7-how-can-i-roll-my-own-task-like-type-to-use-with-async). For reference, what you've provided is the requirements to *await* it from a consumer; however, the requirements for the compiler to *construct* one in an `async` method are much higher. Without `async`, you need to provide the machinery yourself

Comment: I think the i was looking for the async method builder.Thank you ,really interesting thread.