# Sanity check needed regarding a custom Task-like return object

Tags: c#, async-await

I have created an Outcome struct so that I am able to return either a successful result or an error message from any method in my data repositories (the implementation of this isn't relevant to the question, apart from the constructors that receive either a `TResult` for a success, or an `Exception` for a failure).

Every time I use this, as it is for database access, I am running it using `async`/`await`, so the signature of a DB call would be something like `public async Task<Outcome<PersonModel>> GetPerson(PersonID personID);`

I've been trying to figure out if I can use a custom Task-like object (such as `AsyncOutcome<TResult>`) to wrap an `Outcome<TResult>` without needing the double-level generics.  For instance:

```
public async AsyncOutcome<PersonModel> GetPerson(PersonID personID)
{
    try
    {
        PersonModel model = /* get person from the database */
        return new AsyncOutcome<PersonModel>(model);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new AsyncOutcome<PersonModel>(ex);
    }
}
```

```
public async Task TestAction
{
    Outcome<PersonModel> result = await GetPerson(new PersonID(1234));

    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
}
```

However, I've been trying to wrap my head around the limited documentation regarding Task-like objects and `AsyncMethodBuilder` and I just cannot figure out how to do it.

Is this even possible (without rewriting the entire state machine, etc.), or am I on a hiding to nothing?

Has anyone does anything like this before?

Comment: This post is helpful when it comes to implementing custom `Task`-like object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42721979/in-c7-how-can-i-roll-my-own-task-like-type-to-use-with-async

Comment: writing a task-like (`await`-compatible) type is relatively easy; however, writing a type that can be used with `async` is **much much** more difficult; in reality, the number of times you should do this is *almost* zero - I would **strongly** advise you to consider simply using `ValueTask<T>` as the return type here and **forget `Outcome<T>`**. Is there a **very specific** reason you want to use a custom type? keep in mind that once the caller uses `await`, any special functionality in your type will become largely inaccessible

Comment: as for having a `TResult` vs an `Exception`: that seems redundant; both `Task[<T>]` and `ValueTask[<T>]` already know how to deal with exceptions, in the usual expected manner

Comment: "Is this even possible (without rewriting the entire state machine, etc.)," - you would indeed have to write the entire builder engine

Comment: You could argue that `Task<T>` is already a sort of `Outcome<T>`: it has a `Status`, which can be `RanToCompletion` or `Faulted` (among others). It has a `Result` property which holds the result of a successful completion, and it has an `Exception` property which holds the result of an unsuccessful completion.

Comment: I'd say just keep the double generics. Even types like `AsyncLazy<T>` are barely better than `Lazy<Task<T>>`. FWIW, I have a [`Try` type](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Try) but I don't see sufficient benefit to adding an `AsyncTry` type.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I'll look into some of the other options.
Regarding `ValueTask<T>`, I need to be accessing the database on each of these calls, so there will rarely be a time that the result is already determined.
Regaring using just `Task<T>`, the `Outcome<T>` class has been created as an F#-esque Option type, with Match, Bind, etc. functions built into it.  I'll need to see how easy it would be to extend the Task object to obtain this sort of functionality.