# why should we avoid lock(this)?

Tags: c#, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is lock(this) {…} bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad)

In C# to make a critical region thread safe we can use `lock()` statement. The lock statement takes an object. What is wrong if we pass `this` to the lock statement?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx:

> In general, avoid locking on a public
>   type, or instances beyond your code's
>   control. The common constructs `lock
>   (this)`, `lock (typeof (MyType))`, and
>   `lock ("myLock")` violate this
>   guideline:
>
> - `lock (this)` is a problem if the
>     instance can be accessed publicly.
> - `lock (typeof (MyType))` is a problem if
>     `MyType` is publicly accessible.
> - `lock(“myLock”)` is a problem because
>     any other code in the process using
>     the same string, will share the same
>     lock.
>
> Best practice is to define a
>   private object to lock on, or a
>   private static object variable to
>   protect data common to all instances.

Answer (score 7):

Because `this` is not encapsulated by the class and thus it is hard to reason about who locks on this. I.e. in order to find out what part of the code is locking on `this` you need to go through a lot. If, on the other hand, you restrict locking to a private member, it is easy to reason about where locking takes place.