# How would I convert this crypto from C# to C

Tags: c#, c

This is the C# code I use:

```
public void Decrypt(byte[] @in, byte[] @out, int size)
{
    lock (this)
    {
        for (ushort i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (_server)
            {
                @out[i] = (byte)(@in[i] ^ 0xAB);
                @out[i] = (byte)((@out[i] << 4) | (@out[i] >> 4));
                @out[i] = (byte)(ConquerKeys.Key2[_inCounter >> 8] ^ @out[i]);
                @out[i] = (byte)(ConquerKeys.Key1[_inCounter & 0xFF] ^ @out[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                @out[i] = (byte)(ConquerKeys.Key1[_inCounter & 0xFF] ^ @in[i]);
                @out[i] = (byte)(ConquerKeys.Key2[_inCounter >> 8] ^ @out[i]);
                @out[i] = (byte)((@out[i] << 4) | (@out[i] >> 4));
                @out[i] = (byte)(@out[i] ^ 0xAB);
            }
            _inCounter = (ushort)(_inCounter + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is how I converted it to work in C.

```
char* decrypt(char* in, int size, int server)
{
    char out[size];
    memset(out, 0, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (server == 1)
        {
            out[i] = in[i] ^ 0xAB;
            out[i] = out[i] << 4 | out[i] >> 4;
            out[i] = Key2[incounter >> 8] ^ out[i];
            out[i] = Key1[incounter & 0xFF] ^ in[i];
        }
        else if (server == 0)
        {
            out[i] = Key1[incounter & 0xFF] ^ in[i];
            out[i] = Key2[incounter >> 8] ^ out[i];
            out[i] = out[i] << 4 | out[i] >> 4;
            out[i] = out[i] ^ 0xAB;
        }
        incounter++;
    }
    return out;
}
```

However for some reason the C one does not work.

[Link for the full C# file](http://0bj3ct1v3.pastebin.com/4rKFCQHv)

[Link for the full C file](http://0bj3ct1v3.pastebin.com/AsTkSKWH)

[Link for the C implementation](http://0bj3ct1v3.pastebin.com/kUpVvgNL)

Comment: It looks like the C# source was ported from C.  Oh, how fun!  A game of telephone!

Comment: What if (server == 2) ?  `if(server)` is valid C code as well. This is probably not the origin of your problem, but it strikes me as odd.

Comment: lock(this) ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad

Comment: @Xavier has a point too.  The structure of the C code should be `if (server) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: Maybe you have to port the lock() statement as well, but the solution will depend on your platform.

Comment: I would add to the questions about `lock()` and say...  Are you sure you need this synchronized?  Seems like a bad design if so.  You have in and out parameters specified by someone else, it should be the caller's decision if they need synchronization.

Comment: Also, it's best not to try to write your own crypto unless you're familiar with the algorithms, the language you're writing in, how to write securely in that language, and likely pitfalls in writing the crypto.  Translating line-for-line can introduce subtle differences in the code, which likely wouldn't matter for most purposes, but could cause security flaws for crypto.  Find a good library in whatever language you're using, and use it according to directions.

Comment: @David, I'm not using my own crypto, I'm emulating.
@asveikau, the C# code is out-dated, not going to use it in C# anymore. And the C code doesn't need locking (afaik).

Comment: @Basser: Did you also fix the stack/heap allocation error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a translation error.

The C# line:

```
@out[i] = (byte)(ConquerKeys.Key1[_inCounter & 0xFF] ^ @out[i]);
```

Became:

```
out[i] = Key1[incounter & 0xFF] ^ in[i];
```

The value on the right of the xor (^) is from the wrong array.

Additionally, you are returning a stack-allocated variable, which will cause all sorts of problem.

Change:

```
char out[size];
memset(out, 0, size);
```

to:

```
char *out = (char*)calloc(size, sizeof(char));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should've found that out myself.. been looking for over an hour. Sorry for bothering all of you..

Comment: No problem.  When you've been staring at the same piece of code for that long, it's easy to become blind to that sort of error.  Fresh eyes always help.

Comment: Actually, I just found out this didn't fix it. It made it appear to be correct. But it still isn't working. :/

Answer (score 3):

The most glaring error I see is that you are returning a pointer to a stack-allocated array, which is going to get stomped by the next function call after `decrypt()` returns.  You need to `malloc()` that buffer or pass in a pointer to a writable buffer.

Comment: Could you help me out by using an example? This is the first project involving unmanaged code. :/

Comment: Sure.  Replace `char out[size];` with `char *out = (char*)malloc(size * sizeof(char));`.  Note that the code that calls `decrypt()` will be responsible for `free()`ing the memory when it is finished with it.

Comment: @cdhowie, still not working...
I edited my original post and added my implementation.

Comment: Why not just pass `out` as a parameter the same way that you do in the C# code?

Comment: What difference would that make?

Comment: @Basser: Essentially, the caller is allowed to specify where to write the data.  This means that the caller has the opportunity to re-use a buffer that it has already allocated.  Returning a new buffer preempts any such optimization.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a reference to a local variable which is illegal. Either let the caller pass in an array or use malloc() to create an array inside the method.

Comment: No, returning a local variable is not illegal.  Returning a **pointer to a stack-allocated variable** is illegal.  (Or, at the very least, undefined behavior.)  Also, note the difference between "local" and "stack-allocated" -- the former includes function-scoped static variables; the latter does not.

Answer (score 1):

I also suggest turning `char` into `unsigned char` since it is more portable. If your platform assumes `char` is the same as `signed char`, the arithmetic (bit shifts, etc) will not work right.
So just specify `unsigned char` explicitly (use a typedef or include `<stdint.h>` if `unsigned char` seems too long-winded for you).