# How do I prevent a race condition when calling the same function from different threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, race-condition

Hoping for a little guidance on how to avoid a race condition with the below code?

```
class MyClass
{
    private bool isRunning;

    private async void MyEvent() //EventHandler
    {
        await RunThis();
    }

    private async Task RunThis()
    {
        isRunning = true;

        //Do Some Async Stuff

        isRunning = false;
    }

    public Task DoSomeOtherTask()
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            if (!isRunning)
                await RunThis();
        }

        return SomeOtherTask();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Comment: You are looking for a lock. I'm pretty sure this question is duplicated but I have no time to look for the original.
Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544823/what-precisely-does-a-lock-lock or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock

Comment: [Do not use async void](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50932089/7450780)

Comment: If I remember correct, you already posted that question some days ago. In particular the "do not use async void" has already been mentioned, for good reason.

Comment: What is the intended behavior/purpose of your code?

Comment: @DenisMicheal Hi, Thanks for the comment. MyEvent is actually an event handler. I'll edit to make this clear.

Comment: You know the `Task.Run` code in `DoSomeOtherTask` is "fire-and-forget?

Comment: HI...yes, that's fine for my use case. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case you should probably just do all checks on the UI thread, before calling any multi threaded code. It is a bit difficult to tell, but I would assume the intent is to do something like:

```
class MyClass
{
    private bool isRunning;
    private object myLock = new object();

    public async void MyEvent() //EventHandler
    {
        RunThis(false);
    }

    private async Task RunThis(bool onBackgroundThread)
    {     
        // You should also handle exceptions!
        lock(myLock){ // lock is only needed if this can be called multiple threads
            if(isRunning) return;
            isRunning = true;
        }
             
        if( onBackgroundThread){
            return await Task.Run(async () => await RunThis());
        }
        else{
            return await RunThis();
        }  

        lock(myLock){ // not sure if this is ever needed, but better safe than sorry
            isRunning = false;  
        } 
    }
    private async Task RunThis()
    {
        //Do Some Async Stuff
    }
    public Task DoingSomeOtherStuffOnADifferentThread()
    {
       RunThis(true);
    }
}
```

This should avoid any race conditions, and ensure only one `RunThis()` call are done concurrently. That is assuming `RunThis(bool onBackgroundThread)` is only called from the UI thread. If that is not the case you should take a lock while checking and setting the `isRunning` field, or possibly use [interlocked.CompareExchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange?view=net-8.0) to do comparison and modification in a single step.

A good practice is to reduce "shared state" as much as possible, meaning that the vast majority of fields should be owned by (and only accessible by) either the UI thread, or a specific task or thread. The data that *do* need to be shared needs to be tightly controlled and protected. But the topic of thread safe programming is much to large to cover in a SO post.

Note that multi threading is difficult. It is fairly easy to make mistakes, and mistakes can easily result in bugs that are very difficult to reproduce, and therefore also difficult to find and fix. I would recommend reading a fair amount of resources before attempting anything multi threaded.

Asynchronous programming can be a bit easier to use if you ensure all of your code runs on the UI thread. But mixing asynchronous programming and multi threading is even more difficult than either on its own.

Comment: HI, thanks for the answer. I've actually renamed and reworked the code to hopefully make it a little clearer. To clarify further (in my code) the call to RunThis in DoSomeOtherTask could also be active when MyEvent makes a call to RunThis. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @ledragon That sounds like a bug to me. Your current design could allow `DoSomeOtherTask ` to start a task, even if `MyEvent` is still running. Assuming that is not the intent you should either set `isRunning` in a common method (as in my example), or set it in `MyEvent` and check it in `DoSomeOtherTask`. In either case, do both modifications and checks on the UI thread to avoid threading issues.

Comment: I'm actually just trying to shoehorn RunThis into a call from the UI to DoSomeOtherTask but of course ensure that RunThis hasn't already been called (and is currently running) from the event handler...and also ensure that if RunThis is called from the event handler, ensure that RunThis hasn't already been called (and is currently running) from the UI call to DoSomeOtherTask. Clear as mud!

Comment: @ledragon So at most one `RunThis` call running at a time? That should be what my example does, added some locks to the example, if that is needed.

Comment: Well yes, actually completely prevent a second (simultaneous) running of RunThis if it  is currently running. I.e if it's called by MyEvent and is running, prevent it running again if it's called from DoSomeOtherTask...and vice versa if it's called from DoSomeOtherTask, prevent it running again if it's called from MyEvent. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score -1):

FYI answer as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {   
        var myClass = new MyClass();
        
        _ = myClass.MyEventHandler();       
        
        await Task.Delay(500);
                
        _ = myClass.DoSomeOtherTask();
        
        await Task.Delay(3000);
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _lock = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
    
    public async Task MyEventHandler()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"MyEventHandler Started {_lock.CurrentCount}");
        
        await RunThis("MyEventHandler");
    }

    private async Task RunThis(string caller)
    {               
        Console.WriteLine($"RunThis Started {caller} {_lock.CurrentCount} {DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff")}");
        
        if (_lock.CurrentCount <= 0) return;
        
        await _lock.WaitAsync();            
        
        Console.WriteLine($"RunThis Running {caller} {_lock.CurrentCount} {DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff")}");
            
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        
        _lock.Release();
        
        Console.WriteLine($"RunThis Ending {caller} {_lock.CurrentCount} {DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff")}");
    }

    public Task DoSomeOtherTask()
    {       
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"DoSomeOtherTask Started {_lock.CurrentCount}");
            
            await RunThis("DoSomeOtherTask");
        });
        
        return Task.Delay(500);
    }
}
```