# How to fire event out of threading mode

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I used a component for socket connection in C#

I connect 10 tcp object to server by threading.
and I get the recived data in an Event (Data_OnRecived)

here is my code:

// Connect Function

```
    private void Connect(object State)
    {
        Tcp tcp = (Tcp)State;
        TcpSession tcpSession = new TcpSession();

        tcpSession.RemoteEndPoint = new Dart.Sockets.IPEndPoint(IP, Convert.ToInt32(Port));
        tcpSession.ConnectTimeout = 1;

        try
        {
            tcp.Connect(tcpSession);
        }

        catch(System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex) {
            tcp.Marshal(ex);
        }
    }
```

// Initial TCP component

```
    private void TcpInitialize()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MaxConnection; i++)
        {
            SocketControl[i].TCPConnection = new Tcp();

            SocketControl[i].TCPConnection.Data += new System.EventHandler<Dart.Sockets.DataEventArgs>(this.tcp_Data);

            SocketControl[i].TCPConnection.Start(Connect, SocketControl[i].TCPConnection);

            SocketControl[i].TCPConnection.Tag = i;
        }
    }
```

and TCP_Data Event handler that fire when data recived:

```
void tcp_Data(object sender, Dart.Sockets.DataEventArgs e)
        {
             TCP tcp = (TCP) Sender;
             int GlobalVariable = tcp.Tag;
        }
```

my problem is here that tcp_Data will run in threading mode, not in Queque and one by one. can I change it that this event dont start in threading mode?? I mean every data that recived, fire the tcp_Data after another one.

Thanks for any helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to execute only one `tcp_Data` callback at a time. Make `tcp_Data` perform this synchronization. For example, it could take a lock:

```
    object lockObj = new object();
    void tcp_Data(object sender, Dart.Sockets.DataEventArgs e)
    {
         lock (lockObj) {
          TCP tcp = (TCP) Sender;
          int GlobalVariable = tcp.Tag;
          //...
         }
    }
```

You also could queue this work to a [`TaskScheduler` that is single-threaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @urs it didnt change any thing. when I debug this code, I can see that is execute in threading mode

Comment: What do you mean by "threading mode"? And what does your statement have to do with this answer?

Comment: And I provided you a solution for that. What do you think about it?

Comment: now there are more thatn thread at time in tcp_Data event handler with your code. @urs can I chat with you about this problem? I want to explain it clearly...

Comment: There will be more than one thread in tcp_Data, but only one in the locked region. Do you really observe more than one thread at a time in the locked region? If yes, then the lock object is probably not the same each time. Make lockObj static for a test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62914/discussion-between-elahe-and-usr).

Comment: I make lockObj readOnly and my problem solved. but why in this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621438/confusion-about-the-lock-statement-in-c-sharp) : (1) Does the lock statement ensure that no more than one thread is in the body of the lock statement at any one time? The answer is No?!

Comment: The lock body is exclusive only for a specific lock object instance. If you use multiple instances then your code runs exclusively *per lock object instance*. That's what the lock object argument is *for*.