# How to lock a Coroutine?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, locking, coroutine

I have a custom scene manager, which apart from loading scenes calls some events for me. I want it to fully load a scene, before it starts loading another one, so I added a lock. I'm using `Monitor` because I want to enter the lock in `OnLoadScene()` and exit it in `LoadSceneAsync()` and this wouldn't be possible with the `lock() {}` syntax, because `LoadSceneAsync()` is called as a `Coroutine` (asynchronously). I found the `Monitor` syntax here: [C# manual lock/unlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818362/c-sharp-manual-lock-unlock).

Here is the code:

```
public class CustomSceneManager : Singleton<CustomSceneManager>
{
    public delegate void SceneChange(string sceneName);

    public event SceneChange LoadScene;
    public event SceneChange UnloadScene;

    private static readonly object LoadSceneLock = new object();

    private IEnumerator LoadSceneAsync(string sceneName)
    {
        var asyncLoadLevel = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Single);
        while (!asyncLoadLevel.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        Debug.Log($"Finished loading: {sceneName}");
        LoadScene?.Invoke(sceneName);
        Monitor.Exit(LoadSceneLock); // exit lock
    }

    public void OnLoadScene(string newSceneName)
    {
        Monitor.Enter(LoadSceneLock); // enter lock
        Debug.Log($"Started loading: {newSceneName}");
        UnloadScene?.Invoke(newSceneName);
        StartCoroutine(LoadSceneAsync(newSceneName));
    }
}
```

The issue is that it doesn't work as I expect it to. This is how my logs look:

`Started loading: scene_1`

`Started loading: scene_2`

`Finished loading: scene_1`

`Finished loading: scene_2`

Am I using the lock incorrectly?

Comment: I think you can just use a bool here, the only work being done on other threads is the async load, but you're veryifing if it's done in the main thread.

Comment: @mcrvaz I changed the `object` to `bool` but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Yes, I mean that you don't have to use a Monitor, just a `bool inUse` should be just fine.

Comment: @mcrvaz But I need a blocking call so when I call `OnLoadScene()` consecutively all calls will be executed one after another. Can I achieve this with a simple flag?

Comment: Sorry, I tought you needed only to prevent the call. This isn't possible with a simple flag. I was not able to reproduce your expected behaviour with Monitor, but since it blocks the thread it's monitoring, I doubt it would be useful in this case. I would say the easiest approach here would be to create a Queue with your load routines.

Comment: By not useful I mean that it would block the Unity main thread and the loading would never complete. If you started the monitor from another thread maybe it could work, but then you'd have to dodge around Unity limitations from being acessed by external threads.