# What is the difference between lock(this) and lock(thisLock)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I'm reading [lock Statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) where I saw this code:

```
class Account
{
    private Object thisLock = new Object();

    //...

    int Withdraw(int amount)
    {
        lock (thisLock)
        {
           //....
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

I'm wondering if it would make any difference if we write `lock(this)` instead of `lock(thisLock)` in the above example. Please see [the complete example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) if your answer depends on it.

If you think there is indeed some difference between `lock(this)` and `lock(thisLock)` , then please help me understanding the difference with all important points. In particular, what does each *exactly* mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is lock(this) {...} bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference stems from the fact that `lock`, if misused, can result in thread deadlock. If the lock target's visibility is unknown to you (i.e., you cannot be 100% certain who has a reference to the target and if/when they might `lock` it), then you cannot really know if the application might experience a deadlock.

For this reason it's customary to lock on a `private` member: since it's private and it's in your code, you *do* know that noone else can `lock` it.

Of course all this is a purely academic difference most of the time (usually people don't go around locking random objects), but it's a good defensive coding practice.

The page you link to states:

> In general, avoid locking on a public type, or instances beyond your
>   code's control. The common constructs lock (this), lock (typeof
>   (MyType)), and lock ("myLock") violate this guideline:
>
> lock (this) is a problem if the instance can be accessed publicly.

Because someone else might lock the instance using a reference they have, and your code that does `lock(this)` will of course not expect that. [**Example on IDEone**](http://ideone.com/59G3l) (see line 26).

> lock (typeof (MyType)) is a problem if MyType is publicly accessible.

A variation of the above, if the type is visible to other code then you might end up trying to lock the same instance as that code (`typeof` returns singleton instances).

> lock("myLock") is a problem because any other code in the process
>   using the same string, will share the same lock.

Another variation: due to string interning, code ends up trying to lock the same instance.

> Best practice is to define a private object to lock on, or a private
>   static object variable to protect data common to all instances.

Comment: I didn't understand this : `and your code that does lock(this) will of course not expect that.` Why? How can it result in deadlock?

Comment: @Nawaz: Added an example. Does it illustrate the problem clearly?

Comment: I still didn't understand the deadlock. Why is it not possible that the thread X will *start* execute the code inside `lock(this){}` *after* the thread Y finishes executing the critical code for which it has locked on `obj`?

Answer (score 2):

When you do `lock(this)` you don't have full control of `this` because you don't know who else would be using `this` or instance of your class. It is safe to use a local object because that local object would be available only inside your class hence you will have full control on it

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad) for details