# How-To lock in .NET using a class instance, an object, or a type

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, enterprise-library

I'd like to know how you know when to lock an entire type

```
lock (typeof(MyClass))
{
...
}
```

or an instance

```
lock (this)
{
...
}
```

or an object

```
lock (this._lockObj)
{
...
}
```

I am asking this because I have a static class that is a simple Wrapper for Enterprise Library 5 and is accessed by multiple components from possibly different threads. The WriteLog() method is locked. I use the type to lock.

Comment: Related to part of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First rule. Lock using object that is not accessible from outside of class. That's why `this` and various `typeof`s are bad idea. Outer code can interfere with your locks. Then question is what scope of `lock` is it. If it is static then use static field otherwise use instance field.

To pick correct `lock` object you should you identify groups of code that are mutually exclusive. So if you have 4 methods that are exclusive in pairs like A and B , C and D you should have 2 differenet `lock` objects, not 1.

Comment: "Inner" code can interfere with your `lock` object, too, which is why I would stretch your recommendation to "use a dedicated locking object, not even used otherwise internally."

Answer (score 5):

MSDN has this to say: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)

> In general, avoid locking on a public type, or instances beyond your
>   code's control. The common constructs lock (this), lock (typeof
>   (MyType)), and lock ("myLock") violate this guideline:
>
> ```
> lock (this) is a problem if the instance can be accessed publicly.
>
> lock (typeof (MyType)) is a problem if MyType is publicly accessible.
>
> lock("myLock") is a problem because any other code in the process using the same string, will share the same lock.
> ```
>
> Best practice is to define a private object to lock on, or a private
>   static object variable to protect data common to all instances.

I have had few cases to ever need anything other than a private member object to lock on.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to lock an entire type, you should implement a Singleton pattern.
The responsibility for locking should be inside the actual class implementation - otherwise sooner or later you will run into locking issues - especially deadlocks can only be avoided otherwise when you have a locking order.
Not hiding the locking is a recipe for desaster.

Answer (score -1):

The MSDN article suggests locking the type when using a static class/method, so your usage is fine.

It also suggests using 'this' for protecting instance variables.

**EDIT**

As suggested, here is the MSDN article in question:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: You might want to link to the MSDN article in question because this doesn't sound right (as whoever gave the minus one is indicating).

Comment: Yeah looking at things, this was the suggested practice back with VS2k3/.NET 1.1 - I kind of assumed the MSDN article would have defaulted to the most recent iteration...silly me!

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Its quite interesting to see the difference between the 2k3 and 2k5 articles with one recommending something and the next saying don't do it. :)