# lock(X) vs lock(typeof(X))

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, thread-safety

What is the difference between locking on a type of a class vs locking on the class itself?

For example:

```
private readonly object xmpp = new object();

lock (xmpp)
{
    ...
}
```

vs

```
lock (typeof(Xmpp))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: They are both wrong.   This is well covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad

Comment: The first one does not compile.

Comment: i didn't think it was identical as the post you refer to as I am locking on an object, not on itself. Updated the code slightly, think that compiles properly

Comment: I think lock on typeof() is incorrect, it is quite meaningless.

Comment: @ChiaMing It's not meaningless to lock on typeof, which is unfortunate, because it it was meaningless it wouldn't compile, which would be a good thing given the problems locking on types brings.

Comment: I mean, it is not practical. it is more like if + goto vs while.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- `lock(x)` synchronizes on a different lock for each instance of the type
- `lock(typeof(X))` synchronizes on the same lock for all instances of the type

Always lock on a private lock object:

```
 public class X
 {
      private readonly Object _lock = new Object();

      // ...
            lock (_lock)
            {
            }
```

If you **must** synchronize access to *class static members*, use the same pattern:

```
 public class X
 {
      private readonly static Object s_lock = new Object();
```

Comment: I would just like to point out WHY you should always use a private lock object...  Because only your class and code should have access to that lock object, if you lock something publicly accessible someone else could potentially lock your objects and break your code.  This really only applies when writing 3rd party libraries, but it's a good pattern and good habit to get in to everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the comments both of you. Very helpful in my understanding

Comment: I would also recommend adding the `readonly` keyword to the locking object, for clarity's sake.  Not that you would intentionally assign a value, *but* those bugs are always fun.