# how do i wait till the thread complete its job then execute the next command c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, wait

I have the code below (but doesn't work) .. i need to wait till the thread complete its job then execute then next command

```
private void btnPaste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (copiedItems != null)
        {
            if (copy)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread thPASTE = new System.Threading.Thread(PasteFromCopy);
                thPASTE.Start(currAddress);
                lock (this)
                {
                    btnRefresh_Click(sender, e);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread thPASTE = new System.Threading.Thread(PasteFromMove);
                thPASTE.Start(currAddress);
                lock (this)
                {
                    btnRefresh_Click(sender, e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the paste should do some code then after that i should refresh the list im showing.. i need to do it this way, because it doesn't work for me when i call the refresh in the thread
how do i do it ??

Comment: You may also want to consider a private locking variable, instead of taking a lock on `this`.  e.g., `private readonly object lockObject = new object();`  You can see this thread for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad

Comment: There's no point in starting a thread and then wait for it.  You might as well directly call PasteFromCopy()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join.aspx) method on the thread instance which will block the calling thread until the other thread has finished.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [WaitHandles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx) and use the [WaitOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd.aspx) or [WaitAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6.aspx) methods.

Answer (score 1):

`i need to do it this way, because it doesn't work for me when i call the refresh in the thread`

Your problem is not related with thread synchronizations like `Join`, `Wait` , `WaitOne` etc.

> Updating user interface elements from a secondary thread in Windows Forms is tricky because a secondary thread is not allowed to read or write property values directly from a form or any of its child controls. This restriction exists because form objects and control objects in Windows Forms are not thread-safe. The only thread that's allowed to directly access a property value of a form or one of its controls is the primary UI thread

To update your GUI from a thread (other your main thread), you need to call `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke`  methods of your form(or some controls) to insert delegates into the Dispatcher of the UI thread.

These links can help you.

[How to update GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

[Updating the UI from a Secondary Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188732.aspx)

[Updating the GUI from another thread made easy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17688/Updating-the-GUI-from-another-thread-made-easy)