# Interlocked - when do I use it?

Tags: c#, multithreading, interlocked

I just found out about the `Interlocked` class and now I have some basic questions.

From my understanding I should use Interlocked when manipulating numeric variables when multi-threading.  If that statement is true, what about doing reads or just general using of the variables?

For example:

```
if ((iCount % 100) == 0)
```

Do I need to use an `Interlocked` statement there?

What about when I'm initializing the variable:

```
Int32 iCount = 0;
```

I need to make sure I understand this before implementing it.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517951/using-interlocked-usage and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154551/volatile-vs-interlocked-vs-lock

Comment: I saw that post but it skips ahead of my basic questions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are various factors here, but principally *volatility* and *atomicity*. In your statement:

> ```
> if ((iCount % 100) == 0)
> ```
>
> Do I need to use an Interlocked statement there?

we first need to ask "what is `iCount`?". If it is `long` / `ulong`, then it is not guaranteed to be *atomic*, so you absolutely need *some kind* of protection (such as via `Interlocked`) to avoid getting a "torn" value (reading it half-way through being updated, giving a phantom value that it never actually was - for example, changing from `00000000` to `FFFFFFFF` you could read `0000FFFF` or `FFFF0000`). If it is an `int`, it will be guaranteed atomic. The next question is: do I need to see updates? The CPU has various levels of caching built in, and code that *appears* to read from a field can end up *actually* just reading from a local register or cache - and never touching the actual memory. If that is a risk, then you can mitigate that by using `Interlocked`, although in many cases using `volatile` will also guard against this.

The third and trickier question comes when discussing updates: do you want "last edit blindly wins"? if so, just update the value (presumably using `volatile` to allow reads) - however - there is a risk of lost updates if two threads are editing. As an example, if two threads each increment and decrement at the same time the final value could be `0` or `1` - not necessarily what you wanted. `Interlocked` offers ways to do updates with change-detection, and helper methods to do common operations like increment / decrement / add / etc.

Regarding your other question:

> What about when I'm initializing the variable:
>
> ```
> Int32 iCount = 0;
> ```

Field-initializers are only executed on one thread, so do not need additional protection - that is fine.

---

However! Threading is hard. If you are at all unsure, keep it simple: use `lock`. For example (assuming you want per-instance synchronisation):

```
private int iCount = 0;
private readonly object syncLock = new object();
...
lock(syncLock) {
    // code that reads or manipulates iCount
}
```

In many cases, this works fine.

Comment: In my example iCount is an Int32

Comment: @JeffV yes, but IMO you need to understand that **this matters**, hence why I included it in the answer. It would be dangerous if I just said "yes, that's atomic" without that context, because you might change it to `long` in the real code. Equally, atomicity is only a *part* of the story here

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I'm researching the lock(syncLock) construct now.  I appreciate your answer.

Comment: If I'm inserting into a database table should I put a lock around that as well?

Comment: @Jeff complex question - databases have their own locking constructs. Also keep in mind that a database lock is cross-process (and cross-machine), whereas "lock" is single-process.

Comment: the reason why I ask is that there is code that reads and manipulates iCount with a InsertOnSubmit command.  I've noticed that putting the lock around that adds significant time to the process

Comment: @Jeff without a more complete overview of the scenario, I can't comment on that other than to say "oh" (and maybe raise an eyebrow quizically)

Answer (score 3):

When doing multithreading over shared, mutable state you need to synchronize. You do not *need* to use `Interlocked`. `Interlocked` is for advanced users. I suggest you use the `lock` C# statement and only use `Interlocked` for easy cases (increment a shared counter) or performance critical cases.

`Interlocked` can only be used to access a single variable at a time and only quite primitive operations are supported. You will have a really hard time synchronizing multiple variables with `Interlocked`.

In your example, nobody can tell whether you need to synchronize or not because thread safety is a property of the whole program, not of a single statement or function. You need to regard all code operating on the shared state as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to the other answers that Microsoft has additionally introduced ImmutableInterlocked class.

This class is designed for handling Immutable Collections. The class has a set of functions for updating immutable collections using Compare-And-Swap pattern.

You can find it in the System.Collections.Immutable namespace.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.immutable.immutableinterlocked(v=vs.111).aspx