# Can i use Interlocked.Increment inside lock statement?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Can I use it like I've described in the current code?

```
private void Increment() {
    lock(LockObject) {      
         // edit
         // ListOfObjects.Add(someInfo);
         // new edit ---> here
         ListOfObjects.Add(new SomeInfoObject() {
             Account = Interlocked.Increment(ref result),
             // ... other properties
         }
         // Interlocked.Increment(ref result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can but you shouldn't in this case. You're only adding extra overhead. But when it's part of a larger section of code inside a lock, fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lock is not required when you use `Interlocked` class.

MSDN says,

Increments a specified variable and stores the result, **as an atomic operation**.

Comment: It kind of depends whether there's anything else inside the lock block and what you're locking on. For instance it could make sense to increment something that's totally unrelated to the lock with Interlocker.Increment.

Comment: Yes if you have more statements inside the lock construct, then you can do that. From the question's context, it is not required

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, but there should be no reason to do it. Both `lock` and `interlocked` operations work only if all parties involved agreed to do the same. If one thread uses `lock`, expecting that nothing can change while holding the lock, and another thread one uses `ICX` then the ICX thread has just violated the assumptions of the first thread. If both threads agree to use `lock` then the use of ICX inside `lock` is questionable. A single statement `lock` that all it does is an ICX is very very unusual.

You need to post a more detailed description of the code explaining the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use it, but is *redundant* in this case, since nothing else is being protected by the `lock` block.

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9518256/533120) for more info.

**--- EDIT ---**

OK, I see you edited the question to add something to the `lock` block.

In that case, it makes sense to protect this other operation, but whether it *also* makes sense to put `Interlocked.Increment` inside the `lock` block depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Could you provide more context?

Comment: What context do you mean?

Comment: @IamStalker Essentially, what the rest of the code is doing and what is the end-goal you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Just to know if this locking and atomic operations to use in this context?

Comment: @IamStalker If you have only one thread, then you need neither `lock` nor `Interlocked.Increment`. If you have other threads, please tell us what they are doing.

Comment: @IamStalker If `Increment` is not called from multiple threads, then neither is needed. If it is, and it's the only place where `result` is is used, then you don't need `Interlocked.Increment(ref result)` (you still need the `lock`). Otherwise, you need to protect `result` somehow - which _may_ be `Interlocked.Increment`, or _may_ be this `lock` or _may_ be some other `lock`, depending on the situation...

Comment: Sorry I didn't understood you