# FileSystemWatcher with lock on the event

Tags: c#, multithreading, filesystemwatcher

I have the following code:

```
private void WatchFileForChanges()
{
    if (fileInfo.Directory != null)
    {
        _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(fileInfo.Directory.FullName, fileInfo.Name);
        _watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        _watcher.Changed += OnFinalBuilderStatusChanged;
        _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
}

private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    lock (this)
    {
       // here i see 2 different threads coexist
       // even there is a lock!!
       DispatchResult();
    }
}
```

as can be sing in the comment, i am seeing to different threads co-exist in the OnChanged even there is a lock mechanism,
how come??

Comment: Do you realise the implications of [`lock`ing on `this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad)?

Comment: thanks for your answer, but still, why does the 2 threads passed the lock?

Comment: @user829174 Two threads can go through the lock, but not at the same time... That's all a lock does.

Comment: What makes you think two threads are inside the lock at the same time? And are you sure `this` is referencing the same instance? In other words, is there more than one instance of this class in play?

Comment: Brian, there is more than one instance of this class, how can i tell on which instance i am?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lock` does not cause the thread being used to change.  I merely prevents multiple threads from accessing the code within that block at the same time.

The reason you're getting multiple threads here is that `FileSystemWatcher` raises its `Changed` event on a threadpool thread.

If you want to have `DispatchResult` occur on a single thread, you'll need to use some form of `SynchronizationContext` to push the result back onto that thread.  In a UI application, this is typically done via `Control.Invoke` or `Dispatcher.Invoke`, for example.

On a side note, it's a good idea to avoid using `lock(this)`, and instead make a private object that's used just for your locking.  Otherwise, another object could lock on your same instance and cause all sorts of issues.