# Why do we pass self in @synchronized block?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, synchronization, block

I guess @synchronized blocks are not object dependent but thread dependent...right? In that case why do we pass self?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`@synchronized` is a construct provided by the language to create synchronized scopes. As it would be highly inefficient to use a simple global shared mutex, and thus serializing every single `@synchronized` scope in the application, the language allows us to specify a synchronization point.

Then it's up to the developer(s) to decide which synchronization points are appropriate for the task.

On an instance method, using self is common: the instance is the synchronization point. The `@synchronized(self)` scope can be called on any number of instances, but only once for a given instance. Every `@synchronized(self)` scope will be serialized for a given instance.

Of course, you are free to use another synchronization point if you want to do so. You can use the class (`@synchronized(self.class)`) or anything else that suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks! What I need to know exactly is how does the @synchronized(self) differ from @synchronized(self.class)? What I understood from your statement is, when we lock a block with @synchronized(self) it ensures that no two threads will run that block against an object. And when we use @synchronized(self.class), it will ensure that no two threads will run that block against any objects of that class. Am I correct?

Answer (score 5):

I question this practice, as it is a [known anti-pattern in other languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad). The crux of the issue is that someone else could also `synchronize` on your object, possibly causing deadlocks and other issues that would not have been present had you been using a private NSObject for the lock. For example:

```
@implementation foo
-(void) bar
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        @synchronized(sharedLock) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}

Foo* foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
@synchronized(sharedLock) {
    @synchronized(foo) {
         //do something
    }
}

//in another thread
[foo bar];
```

Answer (score 4):

The object passed in is used to differentiate which `@synchronized` blocks correspond to locking each other. Using `self` is often convenient, but sometimes it’s a good idea to use some other object if you want to only synchronise smaller, more specific sections of code (eg. synchronise all access to a specific `NSMutableDictionary`, rather than synchronising everything in the whole instance)

I’m not sure what you mean by “thread dependent”. The purpose of `@synchronized` is for blocks of code that may be running on different threads, and you need to ensure only 1 runs at any time, without overlapping. Important for performing actions that aren’t thread-safe (like mutating collections, for example).

Comment: Oops – yes, it’s a typo. I must have missed that when I fixed all the other ones too :)