# Why isn't @synchronized(self) in Objective-C discouraged like lock(this) is in C#?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My understanding of the `@synchronized(obj) { ... }` directive in Objective-C is that it's essentially the same as the `lock(obj) { ... }` construct in C#, i.e...

- Both create a kind of local, anonymous mutex tied to the specified object
- Any thread entering the `@synchronized`/`lock` block must acquire that mutex prior to executing any code in the block (and will wait to acquire the mutex before proceeding if it's already reserved).

In C#, using `lock(this)` is strongly discouraged (see [Why is lock(this) {...} bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad)) for an example), basically because you then have no control over who locks your mutex or when (since someone else could be using your object as a mutex).

I assumed that concept this would also apply to `@synchronized(self)` in Objective-C, but I was told by a senior developer on my team that `@synchronized` functions differently than `lock`, and the concerns in the above SO post don't apply.

I guess my question is - what am I misunderstanding about `@synchronized`? Why is `@synchronized(self)` safe when `lock(this)` is not?

Thanks.

Comment: This point is raised [in an old post here about `@synchronized()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29218157/603977).

Answer (score 0):

There are different attitudes to things. I had a quick look at the C# answer that you linked to, and if you did the same things with @synchronized, you would be crucified. You should use @synchronized for the absolutely minimum amount of time, and you should absolutely not call anything else that could use @synchronized at the same time. Obey this rule, and you are fine. I suppose in C# you would be just as fine, but in C# they assume that others do stupid things.

There's a simple strategy to avoid deadlocks (if you follow it): Have a set of "level 0" locks: While you hold a "level 0" lock you must not try to acquire any other locks. Then you have a set of "level 1" locks: While you hold a "level 1" lock you can acquire a "level 0" lock, but nothing else. And so on: If you hold a "level n" lock, you may acquire locks at a lower level, but none at the same or higher level. Voila: No deadlocks possible.

A @synchronized that is not at level 0 would be very rare, and you should think very hard about it. There are other synchronisation mechanisms, like serial queues, that work just fine as well.