# Unexpected data loss during static Queue.Enqueue in multithread process

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, aforge

```cs
private Queue<FrameObjectElement> _queueObject = new
Queue<FrameObjectElement>();

private static Queue<FrameObjectElement> _queueItem = new
Queue<FrameObjectElement>();

private static int permitEntryCount = 0;

private int allowThreadEntry = 0;
```

I have 2 queue variables as shown above.

```cs
public Camera(IVideoSource source, MotionDetector detector)
{
    VideoSource = source; 
    _motionDetector = detector;
    VideoSource.NewFrame += VideoNewFrame; 
    MainForm.OnRegisterClickedEvent += new MainForm.RegisterClickedEventHandler(MainForm_OnRegisterClickedEvent);
    MainForm.OnReceiveMultipleFrameEvent += new MainForm.ReceiveMultipleFrameEventHandler(MainForm_OnReceiveMultipleFrameEvent);
}
```

I have a Camera class, and shown above is part of the constructor implementation. The video source always listening to event `VideoNewFrame;` The code I show below is one segment of the code in `VideoNewFrame`.

```cs
FrameObjectElement frameObj = new FrameObjectElement();
frameObj.cameraID = CW.Camobject.id;
frameObj.cameraTag = _FPGAFrameCount / 2;
frameObj.FirstFrameBuffer = BitmapToRgbValues(twoframe_arg.GetFirstBitmap(352, 288));
frameObj.SecondFrameBuffer = BitmapToRgbValues(twoframe_arg.GetSecondBitmap(352, 288));

if (_queueObject.Count > 5)
    _queueObject.Clear();

_queueObject.Enqueue(frameObj);

if (allowThreadEntry == permitEntryCount && isClear) 
{
    if (_queueObject.Count !=  0)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            _queueItem.Enqueue(_queueObject.Peek());
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Thread ID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() +
        " - " + _queueObject.Count.ToString() +
        " queue in QueueObject : Camera ID : " + _queueObject.Peek().cameraID.ToString() +
        " : Camera Tag : " + _queueObject.Peek().cameraTag.ToString() + 
        " : Queue item count : " + _queueItem.Count.ToString());

        _queueObject.Dequeue();

        if (_queueItem.Count == numberOfCamera && isAllow)
        {
            CurrentID = CW.Camobject.id;
            isAllow = false;
        }

        allowThreadEntry++;
        if (_queueItem.Count == numberOfCamera)
        {
            if (CurrentID == CW.Camobject.id)
            {
                isClear = false;
                //allowEntry = false;

                //Debug.WriteLine("-- Count: " + allowThreadEntry.ToString() + " --");

                foreach (FrameObjectElement foE in _queueItem)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Current Camera ID: " + CW.Camobject.id +
                        " : Camera ID : " + foE.cameraID.ToString() +
                        " : Camera Tag : " + foE.cameraTag.ToString() + " :");
                }

                MultipleFrameEventArgs newMul = new MultipleFrameEventArgs();
                newMul.itemObj = _queueItem;

                if (OnMultupleFrameEvent != null)
                    OnMultupleFrameEvent(newMul);

                _queueItem.Clear();
                isAllow = true;
                isClear = true;
                Debug.WriteLine("Queue item count: " + _queueItem.Count.ToString() +
                    " : isClear : " + isClear.ToString());
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Basically what am I trying to achieve here is to collect the frame id, tag, its first and second frame and then store in an object(`struct FrameObjectElement`). Every collection of 2 frames will represent 1 camera tag, thus the meaning of its role here. Then the frameobject is enqueued in `_queueObject`. Next I would have a condition `if(allowThreadEntry == permitEntryCount)`. So what is being done here is every time this function is accessed, `allowThreadEntry` will increment while `permitCountEntry` remains the same. Then this function will go on and enqueue the first element in `_queueObject` to `_queueItem` and once a desired count of `_queueItem` is satisfied, it would raise a signal to another Class. This class will respond back by raising a signal which Camera class has earlier subscribed as shown  `MainForm.OnReceiveMultipleFrameEvent += new MainForm.ReceiveMultipleFrameEvent(MainForm_OnReceiveMultipleFrameEvent)`.

```cs
void
MainForm_OnReceiveMultipleFrameEvent(MainForm.ReceiveMultpleFrameEventArgs
e)  {       permitEntryCount++;     }
```

Upon receiving the signal, `permitEntryCount` will be incremented thus allowing the function to be accessed again. Why I do this is because this class is created depends on how many object camera I have. If I have 11 cameras, I would have 11 `workerThread` running processing this class. I queue up their frames in a non static queue and gather their first element into a static queue which is to be passed for my other process. The problem I am facing here is as below:

```
=============================  Count : 1760 ===============================
Queue item count: 0 : isClear : True
Thread ID: 17 - 3 queue in QueueObject : Camera ID : 3 : Camera Tag :
3372 : Queue item count : 1
Thread ID: 24 - 6 queue in QueueObject : Camera ID :10 : Camera Tag :
4367 : Queue item count : 2
Thread ID: 23 - 5 queue in QueueObject : Camera ID : 9 : Camera Tag :
4415 : Queue item count : 3
Thread ID: 19 - 1 queue in QueueObject : Camera ID : 5 : Camera Tag :
4108 : Queue item count : 4
Thread ID: 20 - 5 queue in QueueObject : Camera ID : 6 : Camera Tag :
3768 : Queue item count : 5
Thread ID: 14 - 1 queue in QueueObject : Camera ID : 0 : Camera Tag :
2837 : Queue item count : 6
Thread ID: 21 - 1 queue in QueueObject : Camera ID : 7 : Camera Tag :
3246 : Queue item count : 7
Thread ID: 16 - 1 queue in QueueObject : Camera ID : 2 : Camera Tag :
3552 : Queue item count : 8
Thread ID: 18 - 6 queue in QueueObject : Camera ID : 4 : Camera Tag :
3117 : Queue item count : 9
Thread ID: 15 - 3 queue in QueueObject : Camera ID :1 : Camera Tag :
2315 : Queue item count : 10
Thread ID: 22 - 4 queue in QueueObject : Camera ID :8 : Camera Tag :
4853 : Queue item count : 11
Current Camera ID: 8 : Camera ID : 3 : Camera Tag : 3372 :
Current Camera ID: 8 : Camera ID :10 : Camera Tag : 4367 :
Current Camera ID: 8 : Camera ID : 9 : Camera Tag : 4415 :
Current Camera ID: 8 : Camera ID : 5 : Camera Tag : 4108 :
Current Camera ID: 8 : Camera ID : 6 : Camera Tag : 3768 :
Current Camera ID: 8 : Camera ID : 0 : Camera Tag : 2837 :
Current Camera ID: 8 : Camera ID : 7 : Camera Tag : 3246 :
Current Camera ID: 8 : Camera ID : 2 : Camera Tag : 3552 :
Current Camera ID: 8 : Camera ID : 4 : Camera Tag : 3117 :
Current Camera ID: 8 : Camera ID : 1 : Camera Tag : 2315 :
Current Camera ID: 8 : Camera ID : 8 : Camera Tag : 4853 :
=============================  Count : 1761 ===============================
Queue item count: 0 : isClear : True
Thread ID: 14 - 1 queue in QueueObject : Camera ID : 0 : Camera Tag :
2838 : Queue item count : 1
Thread ID: 16 - 1 queue in QueueObject : Camera ID : 2 : Camera Tag :
3553 : Queue item count : 2
Thread ID: 21 - 1 queue in QueueObject : Camera ID : 7 : Camera Tag :
3247 : Queue item count : 3
Thread ID: 24 - 1 queue in QueueObject : Camera ID :10 : Camera Tag :
4374 : Queue item count : 4
Thread ID: 23 - 6 queue in QueueObject : Camera ID : 9 : Camera Tag :
4416 : Queue item count : 5
Thread ID: 17 - 4 queue in QueueObject : Camera ID : 3 : Camera Tag :
3373 : Queue item count : 7
Thread ID: 15 - 3 queue in QueueObject : Camera ID : 1 : Camera Tag :
2316 : Queue item count : 7
Thread ID: 18 - 6 queue in QueueObject : Camera ID : 4 : Camera Tag :
3118 : Queue item count : 8
Thread ID: 20 - 6 queue in QueueObject : Camera ID : 6 : Camera Tag :
3769 : Queue item count : 9
Thread ID: 22 - 4 queue in QueueObject : Camera ID :8 : Camera Tag :
4854 : Queue item count : 10
```

I should have different count number in `_queueItem` since every object created can access only one time in this segment thus letting me know that their element will be enqueued into `_queueItem`. But unfortunately, somehow after the program runs a while, there will be an occurrence as shown above. Either I apply lock or not on this part `_queueItem.Enqueue(_queueObject.Peek());` I will still have the problem. May I know where I did wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say the queue is `static`, but you've locked against an *instance*:

```
lock (this)
{
    _queueItem.Enqueue(_queueObject.Peek());
}
```

If you have multiple instances, that means each are locking **independently**. A better approach would be to have a dedicated **static** lock-object, and lock against that. You might be able to cheat with:

```
lock (_queueItem)
{
    _queueItem.Enqueue(_queueObject.Peek());
}
```

if `_queueItem` is never reassigned, but the safest approach is:

```
static readonly object lockObj = new object();
lock (lockObj)
{
    _queueItem.Enqueue(_queueObject.Peek());
}
```

Note that **all** access to the queue **must** be synchronized, and must **all** use the same lock-object.

You might be able to reduce a bit of contention if you talk to the two queues separately, but try to avoid using **nested** locks in this scenario, as that can cause deadlocks if done badly; for example, to peek  from the *instance* queue and enqueue into the *static* queue, you could use:

```
object item;
lock(instanceLock) {
    item = _queueObject.Peek();
}
lock(staticLock) {
    _queueItem.Enqueue(item);
}
```

Note also that even things as simple as `.Count` need to be synchronized, and ideally double-checked (you can't check a count *early* in the method, and then later on assuming there is still something to dequeue, unless you keep the lock for that entire duration). Your code makes repeated use of `.Count` - so please be **very** careful about that. `.Count` is transient: as soon as you've read it, if you relinquish the lock, you must assume that it is already wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Locking using `this` is evil. Check several references:

[Why is lock(this) {…} bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad)

http://haacked.com/archive/2005/04/12/neverlockthis.aspx

Use always a dedicated object like:

```
private static object _queueLock = new object();
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you let the `Queue` handle the locking? Use a [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) which synchronizes internally.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use lock(this) - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad). If you are sharing the queue amongst multiple instance of the class, you need to lock on a static object that is shared by all the instances. Currently each class instance has its own lock, so it will ignore any locks applied by other instances.