# Maintaining open and readonly versions of the same class

Tags: c#, .net, readonly

Lately I have come across quite a few scenarios where an open and a read only version of a class is required. A common scenario is a settings class that users can set properties for but when the settings have been validated and going through a long-running operation, they should only have access to a read-only version.

These classes are not a generic store and are strongly typed.

Currently I just inherit from a read/write version and throw exceptions on write attempts and was wondering if there is a more streamlined way people do this.

Comment: You could follow the `ICollection<T>` methodology of just providing a `IsReadOnly` property. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Why not just have the set return without setting the value once it is validated?

Comment: You don't need to make your *properties* read-only to stop your *users* from setting them unless there is something fundamentally wrong with the structure of your application. What you need is validation logic. Or by *users* do you mean *developers*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that there is a difference between "read-only" and "immutable". Let's say you giving `r` ("receiver") a reference to your object `o` ("object"):

- If you just want to be sure that `r` won't change the value of `o`, then an interface-based solution like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28505835/240733) should suffice and is probably as easy as it will get.

  ```
  var o = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
  r.LookAtList((IEnumerable<int>)o);
  ```

  `r.LookAtList` will see `o` as a read-only sequence because the `IEnumerable<>` abstraction is read-only.
- If you also want to ensure that `r` will always observe the same value for `o`, then that interface-based solution won't be enough. Consider this:

  ```
  var o = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
  r.LookAtList((IEnumerable<int>)o);
  o.Add(4);
  r.LookAtList((IEnumerable<int>)o);
  ```

  While `r.LookAtList` won't be able to change the original object `o` (unless it uses reflection or casts the `IEnumerable<>` back to a `List<>`), it will observe a different sequence the second time around, even though it is passed exactly the same `IEnumerable<>` reference.

If you truly want a read-write version of some type and an immutable version, then you *will* end up with two distinct types. I suggest that you consider the [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern):

```
sealed class FooBuilder
{
    public TA A { get; set; }
    public TB B { get; set; }
    …
    public Foo Build() { return new Foo(A, B, …); }
}

sealed class Foo
{
    public Foo(TA a, TB b, …)
    {
        … // validate arguments
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        …
    }

    private readonly TA a;
    private readonly TB b;
    …

    public TA A { get { return a; } }
    public TB B { get { return b; } }
    …
}
```

But that is quite verbose and you probably hoped to get around all that duplication. Unfortunately, implementing truly immutable types requires a lot of verbosity in the current version of the C# programming language.

This might change somewhat in the upcoming version (6) of C#.

Comment: Thanks. I started writing builder classes and ended up writing an extension to generate them. Don;t see a less complex way of robustly handling this without a truly immutable version.

Comment: @Raheel Khan: Resorting to code generation is probably the next-best thing you can do, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an interface?  Pass the object as the interface where you want it to be read only but pass it as a concrete type where you want it to be read-writable.

```
    public interface IUserSettings
    {
        int Value1 { get; }
        string Value2 { get; }
    }

    public class UserSettings : IUserSettings
    {
        public int Value1 { get; set; }
        public string Value2 { get; set; }
    }
```

You could also then update your UI to display UserSettings and IUserSettings differently (i.e. have 1 template show edit controls and 1 template show read only controls.)

Comment: +1. That's what Microsoft's Common Compiler Infrastructure (CCI) library does (IIRC). And what you can do with collections and IEnumerable<>. However there's one drawback: whoever sees the object via the interface type only gets a read-only version, but not an immutable one: the object's value/contents can still be changed by whomever has a class-typed reference to the same object. If you can pair up this solution with cloneable types, you'd have an easy way around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

My first notion would be to have a struct `FooDefaults` with properties for the default values, and pass that into the constructor for `Foo` (your property class), which uses the defaults (after validation) to initialize members returned from readonly properties.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern used by Microsoft's own `Freezable` hierarchy in WPF does exactly what you describe. See for instance [Freezable.WritePreamble](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Freezable.cs,89271d9bac17b950):

```
        if (IsFrozenInternal)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                SR.Get(SRID.Freezable_CantBeFrozen,GetType().FullName));
        }
```

Freezable uses 'IsFrozen` for clients to figure out whether an object is immutable or not.

Comment: Speaking of "freezing", see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691612/how-to-freeze-a-popsicle-in-net-make-a-class-immutable. Eric Lippert has a series of blog articles about immutability, starting with [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx "Eric Lippert: Fabulous Adventures in Coding: Immutability in C# Part One").

Answer (score 0):

why not just shut down the set?

```
private string prop1 = string.Empty;
public string Prop1 
{
    get { return prop1; }
    set 
    {
        if (ValueIsValid(prop1))
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Prop1");
            return;   // or you can throw an exeption 
        }
        if (prop1 == value)  return;
        prop1 = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Prop1");
    }
}
```