# Can I use dictionary elements as lock objects?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have multiple queues that are being accessed by multiple threads. To achieve thread-safety, I did the following:

```
private static Dictionary<string, Queue<string>> MyQueues = new Dictionary<string, Queue<string>>();

public static string GetNextQueueElementForKey(string key)
{
    string res = string.Empty;

    if (MyQueues.Keys.Contains(key))
    { 
       Queue<string> queue = MyQueues[key];
       lock (queue)
       {
           if (queue.Count() > 0)
           {
               res = queue.Dequeue();
           }
       }
   }

   return res;
}
```

I could also lock `MyQueues`, but then I would lock more than necessary. So my question is, if locking an object contained in a dictionary is going to work - assuming that a key's value (the queue) is never changed.

Comment: Your question reads more like a statement.  What is your question again?

Comment: You don't lock objects, you lock *references to objects*. So in other words, whether the object's value changes does not influence the lock.

Comment: @Nolonar no, you lock on the object itself. You could have 17 references to the same object - they would all lock the same thing.

Comment: @Yogee I don't see what relevance the `GetHashCode()` has here, or why anyone would want to take a `ToString()` on a hashcode - and indeed you should almost certainly *never* lock on a `string` - can you clarify what you are saying there?

Comment: @MarcGravell Actually, when I said "reference", I meant "address where the object is stored". My bad, sorry.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I remove my comment. I check and you are correct. It doesn't lock the hashcode, it lock address of the object.

Comment: @yogee: It does not lock the *address* of the object; the object can have its address moved by the garbage collector! It locks the synchronization block that is in the referred-to object. Of course, this is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *can* - but I generally *wouldn't*. Personally I usually attempt to lock on plain `System.Object` instances which aren't used for anything else, and ideally aren't even exposed to any code other than the class locking on them. That way you can be absolutely sure that nothing else is going to lock.

In this case it looks like you've got control over the queues so you know they won't be used by other code, but it's *possible* that the code inside `Queue<T>` will lock on `this`. That's probably not the case, but it's the kind of thing I would worry about.

Fundamentally, I wish that .NET hadn't taken Java's approach of "a monitor for every object" - I wish `Monitor` had been an instantiable class.

(I assume you're only actually *reading* from the dictionary from multiple threads? It's not safe to use dictionaries for multi-threaded read/write.)

Comment: I only write to the queue when it is empty. I omitted that part in my code above for simplicity. But the queue should be locked in that case, so writing to it should pose no problems.

Comment: But using a plain `System.Object` doesn't work for an unknown number of lock objects.

Comment: @Ben: You can use a dictionary of dedicated lock objects, one for each instance of `Queue<T>`. I still don't see why you're using `Queue<T>` instead of [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16984743/45914).

Comment: @Ben: You could create a `Dictionary<string, Tuple<object, Queue<T>>` - any time you're creating a queue, you create an object. I'm not sure whether I'd do that (and using `ConcurrentQueue<T>` would be my preferred option usually) but it's worth considering.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that it is an element in a dictionary is largely irrelevant - as long as it is a reference type (which `Queue<string>` *is*) - then each queue, when fetched from the dictionary, is going to be the same `object` instance each time. This means it will work perfectly reasonably with locking at the per-queue level.

So basically: yes, that should work fine - as long as the `Enqueue` does the same per-queue locking. As Jon notes - whether you *should* do that is another question.

Personally, I'm still of the opinion that `Monitor` should have been a non-static type, and that you could only lock `Monitor` instances, rather than any `object`.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is, if locking an object contained in a dictionary is going to work - assuming that a key's value (the queue) is never changed.

Looking at your code here:

```
lock (queue) {
    if (queue.Count() > 0) {
        res = queue.Dequeue();
    }
}
```

You *can*, but I would *not* do this. You should [**never** lock on the object itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad), as you might be competing with *other* threads of code that will lock on the same object, including `Queue<T>` itself (who could lock on `this`).

So, at a minimum, you should create a dedicated lock object for each queue.

But, is there a reason that you aren't using [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx)? That'd be the simplest solution, and moves the burden of getting it right to the Framework.