# Two-way binding static DateTime property in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-5.0

I have a number of pages, each page has its own `ViewModel` which inherits from `BaseViewModel`.

On some pages there's a `DatePicker` control of which `SelectedDate` property is binding to a `ReportDate` property in the `BaseViewModel`.

However, I was just told that the `DatePicker` controls on these pages should be using the same date, which means if user changes the date in the control on page 1, when he navigates to page 2, page 2 should show the same date as on page 1.

My first thought would be, to replace the `ReportDate` with a static `DateTime` property, but as far as I know that this is not possible (difficult?) in Silverlight.

Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is dificult at all. here is an example

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
    public DateTime ReportDate
    {
        get
        {
            return ClassHelper.StaticDate;
        }
        set
        {
            ClassHelper.StaticDate = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ReportDate")
        }
     }
}

public static ClassHelper : IPropertyChaged
{
    private static object sync = new object();
    private static DateTime staticDate;
    public static DateTime StaticDate
    {
        get
        {
            return staticDate;
        }
        set
        {
            lock(sync)
            {
                staticDate = value;                
            }
            RaisePropertyChanged("StaticDate")
        }
    }
}
```

and then in the `BaseViewModel` subsicribe to `ClassHelper.PropertyChaged` event and in the handler Call `RaisePropertyChaged("ReportDate")`.

Don't forget to unsubscribe the event in the dispose method in `BaseViewModel`

Of course you might need to change other thinks but this is the base Idea.

Hope that will help you.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/251668/1136211) for an explanation why `lock(this)` is bad. Better lock a private static object member.

Comment: I know it is bad, I put it to stress the fact that it is required to treat the case of concurent change, but since you made the point I chaged it,  thank you

Comment: How can you implement INotifyPropertyChanged to a static class though?

Comment: Actually I have figured it out. Instead of using a static class, I created a singleton class to handle the notification and everything works fine now. Thanks!!