# Getting a lock using an object, rather than this - Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, object, locks

I’m trying to learn threading in C#, and I’ve seen something crop up in few articles but I am not sure I fully understand it:
In the given two examples, what would the fundamental difference between getting a lock on ‘this’  vs ‘thisLock’.

Example 1:

```
class Account
    {
        decimal balance;
        private Object thisLock = new Object();

        public void Withdraw(decimal amount)
        {
            lock (thisLock)
            {
                if (amount > balance)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Insufficient funds");
                }
                balance -= amount;
            }
        }
    }
```

Example 2:

```
class Account
    {
        decimal balance;

        public void Withdraw(decimal amount)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                if (amount > balance)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Insufficient funds");
                }
                balance -= amount;
            }
        }
    }
```

From my understanding, I would of thought that ‘thisLock’ only stops other threads from entering that specific area of code.

Were as getting a lock on ‘this’ would stop all operations on the object, i.e. calls to other methods by other threads?

Have I fundamentally miss understood this, or is that the correct conclusion?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad) helps?

Comment: Sriram's suggestion is the answer -- to be clear, `lock(this)` is in no way different than `lock(somethingElse)` when seen in isolation.

Answer (score 2):

Both cases will have the exact same effect. One difference is that other objects cannot see `thisLock`, so you can be sure nothing else will reuse the lock. If you lock on `this`, another part of code can also lock on the same instance of Account.

Comment: _"you can be sure nothing else will reuse the lock"_ - as long as no other method in that class uses the same lock object.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Of course, but this is something you -as writer of that class- have full control over :-)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is locking granularity.

When locking an object, (simplified) a bit is set on the instance. Anyone else trying to lock the same instance will end up in a wait state until the lock is released by the other.

In many cases, methods on a object can be used at the same time (i.o.w. In parallel). Locking the entire object (this) would exclude the usage of any other method if that method also uses '`lock(this)`'.

Since lock can be used on any reference type, we can create "lock" objects. Where we  implement the '`lock(lockObject)`' on a exclusion basis.

As example;

- MethodA1 and MethodA2 cannot be used at the same time
- MethodB1 and MethodB2 cannot be used at the same time
- MethodA1/2 can be used at the same time as MethodB1/2.

If we would use the `lock(this)` on every method, we would also be exluding MethodA1/2 from running at the same time as MethodB1/2.

By creating 2 lock objects (lockAMethods, lockBMethods) we can now implement our locking more granular.

- In MethodA1 and MethodA2 we'll use "`lock(lockAMethods)`" to make sure the A1 and A2 methods cannot run at the same time.
- In MethodB1 and B2 we'll use the `"lock(lockBMethods)`" to make sure the B1 and B2 methods cannot run at the same time.

We can however `lock(lockAMethods)` and `lock(lockBMethods)` at the same time. Hence we can now run MethodA1/2 at the same time as MethodB1/2.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

You stated

> From my understanding, I would of thought that ‘thisLock’ only stops
>   other threads from entering that specific area of code.
>   Were as getting a lock on ‘this’ would stop all operations on the object, i.e. calls to other methods by other threads?

Whether you use `lock(this)` or `lock(thisLock)` in both the statements, it will only stops other threads from entering that specific area of code.
But as a general practice it is always advised **not to use** `lock(this)` rather create another object and place a `lock` on that object.

**EDIT** yes as `Sriram Sakthivel` has commented, he is absolutely right, please read [Why is lock(this) {...} bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad) for more information why we should avoid `lock(this)`

Comment: The advice to not to use `lock(this)` must be placed in perspective. The Framework Design Guidelines advice against this, because it is bad from a framework perspective. A consumer of your framework can always take a lock on an instance of a type in your framework, which could accidentally lead to a deadlock. When writing a LOB application, there is full control over which code is written and this might not be such a big problem. I would say that in that case `lock(this)` is fine, but using a lock on an instance of another type is actually bad practice.

Comment: Fixed the bad link, you linked current question's link :)