# c++ analog of C#/Java lock(object)

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

In C#/Java I can easily make any thread-unsafe code to be thread-safe. I just introduce special "lockObj" and use it like that:

```
    private object lockObj = new object();

    void ThreadSafeMethod()
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            // work with thread-unsafe code
        }
    }
```

(some people just using `lock (this)` but this is [not recomended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad))

What is easiest and fastest C++ equivalent? I can use C++11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use C++11, use a std::mutex (if you can not use C++11, use boost::mutex)

```
private:
    std::mutex m;

    void ThreadSafeMethod()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
        // work with thread-unsafe code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A Mutex is probably the closest native C++ equivalent.  For the closest equivalent that includes the use of external libraries, you need a Monitor.

However, [std::lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) is probably the straightest line (the provided code example uses [std::mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [std::lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) if you have a C++ compiler or the standard primitives provided by your OS, eg.: WaitForSingleObject on Windows or pthread_mutex_lock on Unix/Linux.