# Protecting against classic deadlock

Tags: c#, multithreading, deadlock

I've been struggling with this problem for about 24 hours now, I just can't seem to find a way around it.

Say I have a collection of Foo objects:

```
public class Foo {
    public int SomeValue;

    public void Execute() {
        lock (this) {
            SomeValue++;
        }  
    }
}

// Instantiated elsewhere and filled with lots of Foos
private static ConcurrentCollection<Foo> fooCollection;
```

Now I'm calling Execute for every Foo like this (I have a multi-core machine):

```
Parallel.ForEach(fooCollection, foo => foo.Execute());
```

---

Now imagine we add a second type of `Foo`:

```
public class Bar : Foo {
    private Foo myFriend;

    public new void Execute() {
        lock (this) {
            SomeValue++;
            lock (myFriend) {
                myFriend.SomeValue += SomeValue;
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

This new `Bar` still locks itself to maintain consistency during `Execute`, and increments `SomeValue`. But it also acquires a lock on its `Foo` friend, so that `myFriend` is updated in a threadsafe manner too, before updating `myFriend.SomeValue`.

The problem I have is that I may have a circular reference chain of `Bar`s, e.g.

```
bar1.myFriend = bar2; bar2.myFriend = bar1;
```

In the worst case:

1. **bar1.Execute()** locks on **bar1**
2. **bar2.Execute()** locks on **bar2**
3. **bar1.Execute()** waits for lock on **bar2**
4. **bar2.Execute()** waits for lock on **bar1**
5. Deadlock :(

---

So, my question is: How do I get around this problem?

Some realistic metrics about my application:

- My real 'Execute()' method does something a lot more meaningful than this example - please just this example on face value :)
- I have about 50,000 'Foos' in my collection. `Execute()` is called on each in parallel by N threads, where N = the number of logical cores on the host machine.
- The expected contention ratio (e.g. where a Foo is waiting on another Foo) is low, maybe 5%. The problem would easy if not for the potential of circular references. Speed isn't really the concern for contended access, just the deadlock situation.

Some caveats:

- In this example, I have used `lock` (`Monitor.Enter/Exit`), but any thread synchronization construct could be used (e.g. a state variable & `Interlocked` methods, etc.).
- The application is performance-sensitive - so for the *uncontended* case I need as much speed as I can get.

I'm hoping there's some standard way of solving this issue that I'm unaware of. I've tried all sorts of gymnastics, but every time I write the worst case out the deadlock is always still a potential.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Yes, that will deadlock.  You'll have to use Monitor.TryEnter() with a timeout so you can back-off on failure and give the other thread a chance to complete.  Worst-case perf is not good.

Comment: You shouldn't use `lock(this)`.  Read [Why it's bad...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, typically to avoid deadlocks we can just prioritise resource, so always try to get lock on the higher priority resources first.

In your case its not as simple as here the objects are of same or derived types.

So a very but twisted way of solving this would be to provide a auto-increment integer to all the instances. Any instance with higher value will be deemed to have a higher priority

so something like

```
foo p1 = this;
foo p2 = myfriend;
if(p1.priority < p2.priority)
{
    foo t = p2;
    p2 = p1;
    p1 = t;
}
lock(p1)
{
    lock(p2)
    {
        // here you can safely increment both p1 & p2 some value. 

    }
}
```

Comment: I was just coming to a similar conclusion myself - if the two objects are intrinsically 'equal' then there's no way to arbitrate between them. So yes, I think you're right - I have to add some artificial 'value' to my Foos. A bit unclean - but does the job fairly efficiently.

Comment: Yeah, here the priority should be instance based solves your problem instead of class based !