# Synchronized locks in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I've got  multi threaded application(for example, servlet). Also I've got a common
 resource(file, ref or something). How can I synchronize its access? This is how I do:

```
    static Object lock = new Object();

    volatile int commonRes = 0;

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Before statement " + commonRes);

        synchronized (lock) {
            //some process
            commonRes++;
        }
        //Do something else
        System.out.println("After statement " + commonRes);
    }
```

I have two questions:

1. Is it good approach?
2. Should `lock` be `volatile`?

Comment: can't you simply lock the method that access the resource? using something like public synchronized void doSomething()?

Comment: I've got no need to sync. whole method. Method could write into file or do some heavy process.

Comment: static lock for non-static field makes no sense for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it good approach?

Locking resources in multi-threaded environments is always good, but marking as `volatile` and synchronizing on the resource is redundant as far as I know since both accomplish almost the same thing in the posted scenario.

When I use synchronized blocks I prefer to lock on the class like this:

```
synchronized(MyClass.class) {
...
}
```

Why i do this:

- both static and non-static methods will be blocked.
- no other external object will be able to lock on your object and possibly create subtle bugs.

Still using `synchronized` blocks like you did is OK too in most scenarios (kinda like the same as what I prefer to do), but if you encounter problems (Performance, things you can't accomplish, starvation), I recommend using a structure like [`ReentrantLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html).
It offers more flexibility and **may** offer some bonus performance. Also it can accomplish things a `synchronized` block can not.

Also something like `ReadWriteLock` or [`ReentrantReadWriteLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) could serve you well in some scenarios so they are worth reading about too.

> Should lock be volatile?

As far as I know there is no reason to. The locking objects are implied to be `volatile` like.

Answer (score 4):

If both threads use the same object to reference the same file, there is no need for a separate `static` object. As your class is descended from `Object`, you can also use

```
synchronized(this) { ... }
```

or the shorthand form covering the entire method

```
public synchronized void doSomething() { ... }
```

The `volatile` is implied in `synchronized` accesses -- the locking primitives are aware they need to be thread-safe.

Comment: Locking on `this` is not that good. If a client decides to lock on a reference of your object, you will have problems. Also it doesn't resolves the problem of static and non-static methods synchronization.

Comment: Check this answer to see a more detailed version of why it is bad (even if it is c#-ish): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad