# Locking on a singleton class for thread safe device IO?

Tags: c#, multithreading, singleton

Say I have the singleton class `Singleton` that can read and write to a `SerialPort`.

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy =
        new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    SerialPort commPort = new SerialPort();

    private Singleton()
    {
        // Setup SerialPort
    }

    public String Read()
    {
        return commPort.ReadLine();
    }

    public void Write(String cmd)
    {
        commPort.WriteLine(cmd);
    }
}
```

Now lets also say that I have multiple threads that access the device at the end of the `SerialPort`. Some threads might only write to the `SerialPort` and some might write and then read from the `SerialPort`.

I want to make sure that while a thread is doing a read then write that it is not interrupted by another thread. Would the way to do this be to `lock` on the `Singleton.Instance` itself?

```
// Running on thread 1
public Boolean SetLEDStatus(int onOff)
{
    lock(Singleton.Instance)
    {
        Singleton.Instance.Write("SET LED " + onOff.ToString() + "\r\n");
        String status = Singleton.Instance.ReadLine();
        return (status.Contains("SUCCESS")) ? true : false;
    }
}

// Running on thread 2
public Boolean IsLEDOn()
{
    lock(Singleton.Instance)
    {
        Singleton.Instance.Write("GET LED\r\n");
        return (Singleton.Instance.ReadLine().Contains("ON")) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

In this instance, if `SetLEDStatus` and `IsLEDOn` were called very close to the same time, I want to make sure that the `SerialPort` is not written too twice before it is read. Does my use of locking prevent that?

Would this type of action be called "transactional IO"?

If this is indeed correct, are there any other more efficient ways to perform that same type of actions?

**EDIT:**

I understand why locking on the `Singleton.Instance` could be bad, if something were to lock on `Singleton.Instance` and then call a method in `Singleton.Instance` that also tries to lock on itself, there would be a deadlock.

I originally planned to use a private object in the singleton to lock on. But I kind of talked myself out of it because of the situation outlined below. Which, I am not sure if this is correct.

(Using the two methods (minues the locking) above running on Thread1 and Thread2)

1. Thread1 calls `Write`, `Singleton.Instance` locks
2. Thread2 calls `Write`, but is blocked by the lock
3. `Singleton.Instance` completes the `Write` and releases the lock
4. Thread2s call to `Write` executes, `Singleton.Instance` locks
5. Thread1 calls `Read`, but is blocked by the lock
6. `Singleton.Instance` completes the `Write` and releases the lock
7. Thread1s `Read` executes, `Singleton.Instance` locks
8. Thread2 calls `Read`, but is blocked by the lock
9. `Singleton.Instance` completes the `Read` and releases the lock
10. Thread2s `Read` is executed, `Singleton.Instance` locks
11. `Singleton.Instance` completes the `Read` and releases the lock

In this case there are two `Writes` to the serial port in a row which is improper. I need to be able to do a `Write` `Read` back to back for some types of communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the lock object, I would use a private **field** on the class (i.e. not static) instead of the singleton instance itself, using the [same reasoning on why not to lock(this) ever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad).

I usually use a declaration looks like this, as declaring the lock object is more readable as self-documented code.

```
private readonly object _LEDLock = new object();
```

This way, when someone else goes to look, they say "Oh, this is the lock object that guards thread access to the LED resource."

IMHO, I think the behavior in the `SetLEDStatus` and `IsLEDOn` methods (with locking) would be better encapsulated in your `Singleton` class as follows:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy =
        new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    SerialPort commPort = new SerialPort();

    private readonly object _LEDLock = new object();

    private Singleton()
    {
        // Setup SerialPort
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This goes in the singleton class, because this is the class actually doing the work.
    /// The behavior belongs in this class. Now it can be called with thread-safety from
    /// any number of threads
    /// </summary>
    public Boolean SetLEDStatus(int onOff)
    {
        lock(_LEDLock)
        {
            var cmd = "SET LED " + onOff.ToString() + "\r\n";
            commPort.WriteLine(cmd);
            string status = commPort.ReadLine();
            return (status.Contains("SUCCESS")) ? true : false;
        }
    }

    public Boolean IsLEDOn()
    {
        lock(_LEDLock)
        {
            commPort.Write("GET LED\r\n");
            var result = commPort.ReadLine().Contains("ON")) ? true : false;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, any calling thread can call these methods in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: Please see my edit to the question about thinking of using the private object to lock on.

Comment: I'm thinking that doesn't really change anything. A private field is exactly functionally equivalent to the locking instance itself. In not using the instance itself, you are not only avoid yourself as the deadlock creator as you mentioned, but you are avoiding others as well. As for the specifics of the order of the reads and writes, it is simple: Anything you need to happen sequentially is inside one lock statement. If your use case is such that this is not possible, which it doesn't sound like it, then you are looking at a larger asynchrony control workflow.

Comment: Also, I would be sure to initialize your singleton before any multithreading occurs, otherwise you could have two threads competing to create the resource itself. I.e. don't have the first call be from either (background) thread1 or thread2.

Comment: "A private field is exactly functionally equivalent to the locking instance itself", does this mean if I have two functions and two private locking objects, if one was locked the other one could not obtain a lock until the first was released? // Also from what I can tell I should be safe on my initialization (http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx).

Comment: Ah, I see the source of the confusion. You have your read/write inside of the lock statement from within the calling thread. I would move that code inside of the singleton instance itself, and the calling threads would not have a lock statement in them. I'll update my code to show you what I mean.

Comment: And as for the two locked objects...they would act independently. You can think of the locked object (e.g. _LEDLock) as the "key" of the critical section created under the hood. I meant that that the private field would be accomplishing the same thing as the singleton instance object itself, but it would change the scope of the object being locked upon (thus changing who has access to the "key").

Answer (score 0):

You should never lock on public objects (on objects that are accesible by the consumer of your code or by yourself outside the type that instantiate them). You always should rely on locking only on private objects so that you will be sure that nobody will make unexpected locks and to arrive into a deadlock situation. Otherwise your implementation is OK, you must allow only one thread to access your port.

Since you already have a private object in your singleton wich is the SerialPort instance, redesign your class like my example below:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy =
        new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private SerialPort commPort = new SerialPort();


    private Singleton()
    {
        // Setup SerialPort
    }

    public String Read()
    {
        lock (commPort)
            return commPort.ReadLine();
    }

    public void Write(String cmd)
    {
        lock (commPort)
            commPort.WriteLine(cmd);
    }
}
```

From the SerialPort documentation, we can deduce that write and read are NOT thread safe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx. So yes, you must sync your R/W to SerialPorts.

Comment: Wouldn't there be an issue that once the `Write` `lock` is released another thread could come in and `lock` again on `Write` before `Read` is locked on, causing the `SerialPort` to be `Write` to twice?

Comment: Of course this can be an issue. Depending of his software design, he migh go by using a producer / consummer aproach and grab a synchronization object such as ManualResetEvent or maybe even a BlockingCollection. What does the code upper is that it will ensure consistency of what data is written so that no two threads will make a mess on the serial port. For him, writing twice maybe is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Does my use of locking prevent that?

Yes, because only one thread at a time can execute inside of these two methods. This is safe and I see no issue with that. Consider locking on a private object created with `new object()`. That's a little safer because it guards against certain bugs.

> Would this type of action be called "transactional IO"?

That term is not well known. Whatever it means this is not "transactional IO".

Comment: Please see my edit to the question about thinking of using the private object to lock on.

Comment: @KDecker the issue you mention does not apply because you are not locking reads and writes. You are locking at the level of SetLEDStatus and IsLEDOn. All operations are correctly paired at all times.