# Parallel.Invoke and thread invocation - Clarification?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.invoke

I have this code which creates a deadlock :

```
void Main()
{
    ClassTest test = new ClassTest();
    lock(test)
    {

        Task t1 = new Task(() => test.DoWorkUsingThisLock(1));
        t1.Start();
        t1.Wait();

    }
}

public class ClassTest
{
    public void DoWorkUsingThisLock(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before " + i);
        Console.WriteLine ("Current Thread ID is = "+Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        lock(this)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Work " + i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done " + i);
    }
}
```

Result :

> Before 1
>   (and deadlock....)

I know that this is a bad practice to lock over instances beyond code's control or  , `this`. But it's just for this question.

I can understand why a deadlock is created here.

The main thread acquires the `lock(test)` in `main` and then a *new* thread starts to invoke  `DoWorkUsingThisLock` - there it tries to acquire a lock over the *same* instance variable and it's stuck ( because of `t1.Wait()` at `main`)

OK

But I've seen this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17031960/859154) which *also* creates deadlock.

```
void Main()
{
    ClassTest test = new ClassTest();
    lock(test)
    {
        Parallel.Invoke (
            () => test.DoWorkUsingThisLock(1),
            () => test.DoWorkUsingThisLock(2)
        );
    }
}

public class ClassTest
{
    public void DoWorkUsingThisLock(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before ClassTest.DoWorkUsingThisLock " + i);
        lock(this)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ClassTest.DoWorkUsingThisLock " + i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("ClassTest.DoWorkUsingThisLock Done " + i);
    }
}
```

The result is :

> Before ClassTest.DoWorkUsingThisLock 1
>   Before ClassTest.DoWorkUsingThisLock 2
>   ClassTest.DoWorkUsingThisLock 1   // <---- how ?
>   ClassTest.DoWorkUsingThisLock Done 1

**Question:**

How come  it DID acquire the lock for the first invocation (<sub>`DoWorkUsingThisLock(1)`</sub>)? The  `lock` at `main` is still blocked due to `Parallel.Invoke`  which DOES block !
I don't understand how the thread has succeeded to enter the `lock(this)` section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Parallel` class uses the current thread to do a part of the work. This is a nice performance optimization but it is observable in the case of thread-specific state.

The TPL has this kind of "inline execution" in many places and it causes a lot of trouble in different ways. Many programs are not made to deal with reentrancy.