# Saving png as bmp introduces peculiar artifacts

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, png, bmp

I have a 3600*3600 pixel [png file](http://s1.uploads.im/yRpra.png)

[image]

that I am trying to save as a bmp using this code

```
var bmpSource = Path.ChangeExtension(source, "bmp");
lock (FileAccessString)
{
    if (!File.Exists(bmpSource))
    {
        var dummy = Image.FromFile(source);
        dummy.Save(bmpSource, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    }
}
```

The result is

[image]

which is pretty close, but there are areas visible to the eye (particularly on the left-hand side) that are not correct.

What could be causing this weird artifact?

Comment: Could they be transparent pixels in the original?

Comment: Side note: [don't lock an strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804879/is-it-ok-to-use-a-string-as-a-lock-object).

Comment: I downloaded first image, then used your same code. It works fine for me. No mismatch in pixels. Not sure why!!

Comment: @Steve: Every pixel has a 0x5F transparency

Comment: Can you give a link to the original file? This small copy doesn't have anything peculiar in the regions of the artifacts. Also: Do make sure about transparency pixels Steve noted!! These will not work in BMP files!

Comment: @TaW: Done - http://s1.uploads.im/yRpra.png

Comment: Hm, this is clean (of tranparent pixels) as well. And like  Sriram Sakthivel says: Your code works just fine without any artifacts. (Without the undefined Lock(FileAccessString), thoigh).. It is reproducable? Does it happen with other images??

Comment: Can you also upload your result BMP?

Comment: `pngcheck` shows the original PNG uses various filters: `up`, `sub`, `avg`, and [`paeth`](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Filters.html#Filter-type-4-Paeth). In particular, that last one is tricky to implement -- see the **Note** in the specifications. It looks like there is a small error in .net's implementation, but without the result BMP it's hard to pin down where exactly.