# Directory creation and concurrency

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, asp.net-core

When requiring to create a folder in an action API, would there be any concurrency issue involved? If so, would the proper solution be to use a lock as in the following code

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(User user){
     ...
     var file = HttpContext.Request.Form.File["SomeFile"];
     ...
     var path = Path.Combile(hostingEnvironment.WebRoot, configurationRoot["BaseDirectory"], user.Id);
     lock(path){
         if(!Directory.Exists(path)){
             Directory.CreateDirectory (path);
         }
     }
     ...
}
```

Would it be also logical to use the `path` variable as the lock object?

Comment: Don't use strings to lock. Ever.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804879/is-it-ok-to-use-a-string-as-a-lock-object

Comment: @spender: Why? can you please explain.

Comment: @spender: Understood, thanks for the great great advice.

Comment: Why are you trying to lock at all? `CreateDirectory` won't throw if the directory exists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just call `Directory.CreateDirectory` and don't stress about concurrency.

From the docs ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx )
:

> If the directory already exists, this method does not create a new
>   directory, but it returns a DirectoryInfo object for the existing
>   directory.

Comment: Isn't that `Directory.CreateDirectory`?

Comment: It's also `CreateDirectory`, sorry I made the actual mistake! :D