# Creating an object from string and using as monitor in synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, synchronized, java-threads

I am using an annotation on some classes and by reflection I get some string of that annotation which is unique for every class.

I am thinking of using that string to synchronize a block of code, but I want to block access of the code only if annotation string value is same, if string is not same than another thread can enter a perform its task. I know that I can't use string directly and ints don't have monitor so I can't use hashcode directly. Is this way going to create any issue when I use jMeter to load test this piece of code.

```
public class LockObject {

   private String lockString;

   public LockObject(String lockString) {
       this.lockString = lockString;
   }

   public int hashCode() {
       returns hashcode for string;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   }
}

public class TestClass {

   public void someMethod() {
       String annotationString = "fetchedByAnnotation that i use on some class by reflection";
       //what i want if string is same then second thread won't enter this block
       synchronized (new LockObject(annotationString)) {
           //some task based on that string
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that I can't use string directly and ints don't have monitor so
> I can't use hashcode directly.

Yes, nonetheless, you could (*but you should not*) take advantage of the method [intern()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#intern()). From [source](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-intern) one can read:

> The java string intern() method returns the interned string. It
> returns the canonical representation of string.
>
> It can be used to return string from memory, if it is created by new
> keyword. It creates exact copy of heap string object in string
> constant pool.

```
String annotationString = // ...;
synchronized (annotationString.intern())
```

Notwithstanding, the problem of locking on strings is that other objects could inadvertently be locking on those same strings for entirely different purposes. In other words, strings have a global semantic scope, that you *cannot control*, *i.e.,* ensure that those same strings are not being used elsewhere as a locking mechanism. From this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804879/is-it-ok-to-use-a-string-as-a-lock-object) (among other points) one can read:

> Locking on strings is discouraged, the main reason is that (because of
> string-interning) some other code could lock on the same string
> instance without you knowing this. Creating a potential for deadlock
> situations.
>
> Now this is probably a far fetched scenario in most concrete
> situations. It's more a general rule for libraries.

An alternative solution would be to have a `Map` of `<String, Object>` where the `key` is the string read from the annotation, and the `value` would be an object which threads can use to synchronize.

The `Map` would be shared among threads, therefore one would have to ensure [mutual exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) when accessing such a `Map`. Every time a thread reads a string from an annotation adds that string to the `Map` if not yet added, otherwise synchronizes on the `value` associated with that string `key`.

Comment: I would have a look at a striped lock. So just an array of lock objects and use the hash of the string to determine the lock index.

Comment: @pveentjer Yep, I agree, it goes directly to the point, with the added benefit of a more sophisticated locking mechanism, albeit slight more complex as well.