# How to dynamically lock strings, but remove the lock objects from memory?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I have the following situation:

I have a lot of threads in my project, and each thread process one "key" by time.

Two threads cannot process the same "key" at the same time, but my project process A LOOOOOT OF KEYS, so I can't store the "keys" on memory, I need to store on memory that a thread is processing a "key" and if another thread tries to process the same "key" this thread will be waiting in a `lock` clause.

Now I have the following structure:

```
public class Lock
{
    private static object _lockObj = new object();
    private static List<object> _lockListValues = new List<object>();

    public static void Execute(object value, Action action)
    {
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            if (!_lockListValues.Contains(value))
                _lockListValues.Add(value);
        }

        lock (_lockListValues.First(x => x.Equals(value)))
        {
            action.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

It is working fine, the problem is that the keys aren't being removed from the memory. The biggest trouble is the multi thread feature because at any time a "key" can be processed.

How could I solve this without a global lock independent of the keys?

Comment: Could you not  use a concurrent queue? Make a single thread that passes the keys onto the queue and make it so that the other threads pull one key from the queue and process it. By using the concurrent queue you can ensure that only one thread has the key at a time.

Comment: It is not safe to obtain a global lock to do Contains and Add but then iterate the list outside that lock.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond If I do that, I will lose a lot of processing of my software, because all the process will taper on the same queue. I can create one queue for each key at execution time, but it will change all my structure (that is very big).

Comment: @mikez I can't see what is not safe with my current structure, could you tell me?

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind You are calling First outside any locks. The call to First must occur within the global lock.

Comment: @mikez Really, so you have some idea to help me about how do what I need?

Comment: You should be accessing `_lockListValues` within your `lock(_lockObj)`, and you aren't removing the keys from the list after your invoke.  You probably should be passing the value into the action, and there is also likely a better way of handling your multithreading as well, but you haven't given enough information to help you out there.

Comment: @RobertMcKee If I access `_lockListValues` within `lock(_lockObj)` don't make sense use the dynamic lock, because every threads will be locked in the same object `_lockObj` right?

Comment: `object key; lock (_lockObj) { if (!_lockListValues.Contains(value)) _lockListValues.Add(value); key=lockListValue.First(x=>x.Equals(value));}lock(key){...}` feel free to optimize it in the case it is found.

Comment: That fixes that problem, but without seeing your key removal code, you will likely remove the key before you should if another thread gets blocked.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Oh, now I understood. There is a problem in my current code. But there isn't any solution to remove the key safely?

Comment: Related: [Asynchronous locking based on a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138179/asynchronous-locking-based-on-a-key)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but no, this is not the way it should be done.

First, you speak about keys, but you store keys as type object in List and then you are searching with LINQ to get that from list.

For that kind of stuff is here dictionary.

Second, object model, usually it is best to implement locking of some object around some class, make it nice and clean:

like:

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;


public LockedObject<T>
{
    public readonly T data;
    public readonly int id;
    private readonly object obj = new object();
    LockedObject(int id, T data)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;

    }

    //Usually, if you have Action related to some data,
    //it is better to receive
    //that data as parameter

    public void InvokeAction(Action<T> action)
    {
        lock(obj)
        {
            action(data);
        }
    }

}

//Now it is a concurrently safe object applying some action
//concurrently on given data, no matter how it is stored.
//But still, this is the best idea:


ConcurrentDictionary<int, LockedObject<T>> dict =
new ConcurrentDictionary<int, LockedObject<T>>();

//You can insert, read, remove all object's concurrently.
```

But, the best thing is yet to come! :) You can make it lock free and very easily!

**EDIT1:**

ConcurrentInvoke, dictionary like collection for concurrently safe invoking action over data. There can be only one action at the time on given key.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;


public class ConcurrentInvoke<TKey, TValue>
{
    //we hate lock() :)

    private class Data<TData>
    {
        public readonly TData data;
        private int flag;
        private Data(TData data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }
        public static bool Contains<TTKey>(ConcurrentDictionary<TTKey, Data<TData>> dict, TTKey key)
        {
            return dict.ContainsKey(key);
        }
        public static bool TryAdd<TTKey>(ConcurrentDictionary<TTKey, Data<TData>> dict, TTKey key, TData data)
        {
            return dict.TryAdd(key, new Data<TData>(data));
        }
        // can not remove if,
        // not exist,
        // remove of the key already in progress,
        // invoke action of the key inprogress
        public static bool TryRemove<TTKey>(ConcurrentDictionary<TTKey, Data<TData>> dict, TTKey key, Action<TTKey, TData> action_removed = null)
        {
            Data<TData> data = null;
            if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out data)) return false;

            var access = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref data.flag, 1, 0) == 0;
            if (!access) return false;

            Data<TData> data2 = null;
            var removed = dict.TryRemove(key, out data2);

            Interlocked.Exchange(ref data.flag, 0);

            if (removed && action_removed != null) action_removed(key, data2.data);
            return removed;
        }
        // can not invoke if,
        // not exist,
        // remove of the key already in progress,
        // invoke action of the key inprogress
        public static bool TryInvokeAction<TTKey>(ConcurrentDictionary<TTKey, Data<TData>> dict, TTKey key, Action<TTKey, TData> invoke_action = null)
        {
            Data<TData> data = null;
            if (invoke_action == null || !dict.TryGetValue(key, out data)) return false;

            var access = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref data.flag, 1, 0) == 0;
            if (!access) return false;

            invoke_action(key, data.data);

            Interlocked.Exchange(ref data.flag, 0);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private 
    readonly
    ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Data<TValue>> dict =
    new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Data<TValue>>()
    ;

    public bool Contains(TKey key)
    {
        return Data<TValue>.Contains(dict, key);
    }
    public bool TryAdd(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        return Data<TValue>.TryAdd(dict, key, value);
    }
    public bool TryRemove(TKey key, Action<TKey, TValue> removed = null)
    {
        return Data<TValue>.TryRemove(dict, key, removed);
    }
    public bool TryInvokeAction(TKey key, Action<TKey, TValue> invoke)
    {
        return Data<TValue>.TryInvokeAction(dict, key, invoke);
    }
}




ConcurrentInvoke<int, string> concurrent_invoke = new ConcurrentInvoke<int, string>();

concurrent_invoke.TryAdd(1, "string 1");
concurrent_invoke.TryAdd(2, "string 2");
concurrent_invoke.TryAdd(3, "string 3");

concurrent_invoke.TryRemove(1);

concurrent_invoke.TryInvokeAction(3, (key, value) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("InvokingAction[key: {0}, vale: {1}", key, value);
});
```

Comment: Your `ConcurrentAccess<T>` class is very clever. I like it! however `dict.Add(t);` will not compile because `ConcurrentDictionary<T>` does not have a non-try `Add` method. You likely want `AddOrUpdate`, but be aware this does give a small window where someone could call `TryInvokeAction`, another method calls `TryAdd` and gets a `true` result, then the invoked action finishes and overwrites the added value and also returns `true`. You could solve this problem with a 2nd dictionary or a thread safe `HashSet<int>` of keys that you check before calling `TryAdd`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, you are right, TryAdd and key uniqueness, I made an assumption about already unique keys!  Yes, the second dictionary could work. That second class was a nice idea before sleep. I will improve it as edit:). I think I found today possible use in some other scenario, just not as static implementation...
Thanks for thinking about it:).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a robust and performant inplementation of the `Lock` class, based on a [`ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2) collection:

```
public static class Lock
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<object, Entry> _entries = new();

    private readonly record struct Entry(object Locker, int RefCount);

    public static void Execute(object key, Action action)
    {
        object locker = GetLocker(key);
        bool lockTaken = false;
        try
        {
            Monitor.Enter(locker, ref lockTaken);
            action();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (lockTaken) Monitor.Exit(locker);
            ReleaseLocker(key, locker);
        }
    }

    private static object GetLocker(object key)
    {
        Entry entry = _entries.AddOrUpdate(key,
            static _ => new Entry(new object(), 1),
            static (_, entry) => entry with { RefCount = entry.RefCount + 1 });
        return entry.Locker;
    }

    private static void ReleaseLocker(object key, object locker)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            bool exists = _entries.TryGetValue(key, out Entry entry);
            if (!exists)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Key not found.");
            if (!ReferenceEquals(entry.Locker, locker))
                new InvalidOperationException("Unknown locker.");
            if (entry.RefCount > 1)
            {
                Entry newEntry = entry with { RefCount = entry.RefCount - 1 };
                if (_entries.TryUpdate(key, newEntry, entry))
                    break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (_entries.TryRemove(KeyValuePair.Create(key, entry)))
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation is based on an answer of a similar question: [Asynchronous locking based on a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138179/asynchronous-locking-based-on-a-key/65256155#65256155). You could look at that answer for a detailed explanation of how it works.

The two `InvalidOperationException` exceptions, `"Key not found."` and `"Unknown locker."`, should never be thrown. If any of these is ever thrown, it will be an indication of a logical error in the above implementation.