# What should be locked for the same string?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, string-interning

I have a method that accepts a `string` parameter, and the method will be called concurrently. I want to lock between calls that pass in the same string. For example, two threads pass in `"abc"` to call the method at the same time, then I hope they one by one. At the same time, the call to `"xyz"` from another thread is not affected. So what should I lock?

```cs
void Foo(string s) {
   lock(what) {} // ???
}
```

I am currently locking `String.Intern(s)`, but I understand that this will increase the uncollectable interned string, and this method will be called countless times by passing countless different strings during the app running, so I want to improve it.

Comment: Check out the answer here for code that will lock on a specific value https://stackoverflow.com/a/31194647/302918

Comment: @Enigmativity I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33786579/how-to-dynamically-lock-strings-but-remove-the-lock-objects-from-memory "How to dynamically lock strings but remove the lock objects from memory") question is a more suitable duplicate (than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138179/asynchronous-locking-based-on-a-key)), because it explicitly asks for removing unused locks from memory, and it refers to synchronous locking. Using asynchronous lockers synchronously adds overhead, without offering anything in return.