# Locking on string-key

Tags: c#, locking

How do I perform a `lock` based on a specific string-key?

```
public void PerformUpdate(string key)
{
    // TODO: Refine this, since they key-string won't 
    // be the same instance between calls

    lock(key)
    {
        PerformUpdateImpl()
    }
}
```

I've tried to keep lock-objects in a `ConcurrentDictionary`, but somehow this doesn't hold up either.

Comment: It locks by reference, the content is next to irrelevant.

Comment: @Lloyd What does that mean? That two different users/threads that pass the same text in the string, but not the same string, will still make above scenario work?

Comment: Lock on a string is a very bad idea: See the remarks in sthe docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Take a look at [stackoverflow.com/questions/4954626](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954626/how-lock-by-method-parameter)

Comment: @seb Strings are immutable so would present problems, see the link Jan provided.

Comment: @Jan I think that remark is only about constant strings though which reference the same object when compiling.

Comment: @poke no, thats true for every string variable in your program. When the value is the same as your constant or variable lock string, its the same reference.

Comment: @poke Strings get interned, check out this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx

Comment: @Lloyd Interesting, didn’t know that. But still, the actual string references are different, and I can lock on a constant string and the same string built with a string builder just fine and they both work concurrently. So unless you explicitely lock on the intern string, this does not really work.

Answer (score 9):

Although this isn't concurrent (you can make it so), what about `Dictionary<string,object>`.

Wouldn't this work?

```
dict.Add("somekey",new object());

lock (dict["somekey"]) {
  ...
}
```

This would allow a thread to lock a named instance of an object, which would I think do what you want.

Comment: Where would the `dict.Add` happen? It seems like this has the potential to cause race conditions on the dictionary.

Comment: Yes. I said it wasn't concurrent it was to just show a concept. You can get around this using `ConcurrentDictionary<>` with .NET 4 and beyond.

Answer (score 2):

One way I've done something similar to this is by creating a `Dictionary<string,object>` and using this to go from the string to the object I am locking on. You may need to ensure that this dictionary is being accessed in a threadsafe fashion (eg a lock around it) and if you need to lock between different instances make it static, etc. But this is the broad technique I've used to do this.