# ASP .Net 2, Classic Pipeline on IIS 8 64 bit scalability issues

Tags: mysql, asp.net, iis, scalability

Apologies for the fairly generic nature of the question - I'm simply hoping someone can contribute some suggestions and/or ideas as I'm out of both!

The background:
We run a fairly large (35M hits/month, peak around 170 connections/sec) site which offers free software downloads (stricly legal) and which is written in ASP .NET 2 (VB .Net :( ). We have 2 web servers, sat behind a dedicated hardware load balancer and both servers are fairly chunky machines, Windows Server 2012 Pro 64 bit and IIS 8. We serve extensionless URLs by using a custom 404 page which parses out the requested URL and Server.Transfers appropriately. Because of this particular component, we have to run in classic pipeline mode.
DB wise we use MySQL, and have two replicated DBs, reads are mainly done from the slave. DB access is via a DevArt library and is extensively cached.

The Problem:
We recently (past few months) moved from older servers, running Windows 2003 Server and IIS6. In the process, we also upgraded the Devart Component and MySql (5.1). Since then, we have suffered intermitted scalability issues, which have become significantly worse as we have added more content. We recently increased the number of programs from 2000 to 4000, and this caused response times to increase from <300ms to over 3000ms (measured with NewRelic). This to my mind points to either a bottleneck in the DB (relatively unlikely, given the extensive caching and from DB monitoring) or a badly written query or code problem.
We also regularly see spikes which seem to coincide with cache refreshes which could support the badly written query argument - unfortunately all caching is done for x minutes from retrieval so it can't always be pinpointed accurately.
All our caching uses locks (like this [What is the best way to lock cache in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112/what-is-the-best-way-to-lock-cache-in-asp-net)), so it could be that one specific operation is taking a while and backing up requests behind it.

The problem is... I can't find it!! Can anyone suggest from experience some tools or methods? I've tried to load test, I've profiled the code, I've read through it line by line... NewRelic Pro was doing a good job for us, but the trial expired and for political reasons we haven't purchased a full licence yet. Maybe WinDbg is the way forward?

Looking forward to any insight anyone can add :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to guess on a solution.  Things could get painful or expensive quickly.  You really should start with some standard/common triage techniques and make an educated decision.

Standard process for troubleshooting performance problems on a data driven app go like this:

1. Review DB indexes (unlikely) and tune as needed.
2. Check resource utilization: CPU, RAM. If your CPU is maxed-out, then consider adding/upgrading CPU or optimize code or split your tiers. If your RAM is maxed-out, then consider adding RAM or split your tiers.  I realize that you just bought new hardware, but you also changed OS and IIS.  So, all bets are off.  Take the 10 minutes to confirm that you have enough CPU and RAM, so you can confidently eliminate those from the list.
3. Check HDD usage: if your queue length goes above 1 very often (more than once per 10 seconds), upgrade disk bandwidth or scale-out your disk (RAID, multiple MDF/LDFs, DB partitioning).  Check this on each MySql box.
4. Check network bandwidth (very unlikely, but check it anyway)
5. Code: a) Consider upgrading to .net 3.5 (or above).  It was designed for better scalability and has much better options for caching.  b) Use newer/improved caching. c) pick through the code for harsh queries and DB usage. I have had really good experiences with RedGate Ants, but equiv. products work good too.

And then things get more specific to your architecture, code and platform.

There are also some locking mechanisms for the Application variable, but they are rarely the cause of lockups.

You might want to keep an eye on your pool recycle statistics.  If you have a memory leak (or connection leak, etc) IIS might seem to freeze when the pool tops-out and restarts.

Comment: Thanks for you comments, they certainly make sense - Points 1-4 have already been covered but definitely worth another go!
Re using a profiler - what do you think about using ANTS on a production server? So far we have limited it to dev/staging, but with little benefit.

Comment: I only profile on a production server as a last-resort.  You could use a snapshot tool to make a VM of your prod server and test it on a VM Host (VPC or HyperV).  (commonly known as a "Staging" server).  Same thing for any other tiers.  Of course, it would be hard to confirm the contention problem unless you were using a traffic generator like WCAT. http://www.iis.net/search?searchterm=wcat

Comment: Thanks again, we used WCAT locally but again with little benefit - looks like we will be trying more load locally and WinDbg on the prod servers.