# What is the best way to lock cache with async calls?

Tags: c#, caching, asynchronous

There are a number of ready-to-use solutions to lock asp.net/mvc cache for long running calls to backend systems (such as DB or WCF service) to avoid subsequent requests by other users, e.g. [What is the best way to lock cache in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112/what-is-the-best-way-to-lock-cache-in-asp-net)

Could you recommend any solution when a call to the backend system should be done as async call?

Is "locking an await call" feasible at all as some articles (e.g. [Why can't I use the 'await' operator within the body of a lock statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612602/why-cant-i-use-the-await-operator-within-the-body-of-a-lock-statement)) conclude that "**it is an incredibly bad idea**"?

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: An alternative for in-memory caches is to cache the `Task<T>` itself instead of the result of the task. This is an easy way to ensure multiple calls only result in a single backend call. However, this approach will also cache exceptions as well as results, so you'd have to take that into consideration.